# How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?

Tags: command-line, suspend, power-management, hibernate

How can I suspend or hibernate my laptop using command line, without installing additional software?

Comment: For Ubuntu 16.04, see this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/777178/suspend-command-in-ubuntu-16-04 and its answer `systemctl suspend`

Comment: Related: [How do I lock the screen from a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/q/184728/327339)

Answer (score 494, accepted):

Traditionally ubuntu supported a fairly blunt method of suspend and hibernate. Neither would integrate well with other apps and sometimes not even work on some machines. This new method doesn't require root and notifies all applications listening for power events.

#### Systemd Method

Starting with Ubuntu 16.04, `systemctl` call must be used (See [Suspend command in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777178/suspend-command-in-ubuntu-16-04))

```
systemctl suspend
```

and

```
systemctl hibernate
```

#### New Method (obsolete)

Obsolete circa Ubuntu 16.04; use `systemctl` instead, as above.

See the answer here on this page [from Adam Paetznick regarding the use of dbus](https://askubuntu.com/a/131022/12637). Ideally you would create a `~/bin/suspend` shortcut/script that makes the use of this action easy.

For use over ssh, you should [modify policykit rules as outlined by Peter V. Mørch](https://askubuntu.com/a/79927/12637)

#### Old Method

According to the [Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=813387) you can use the following commands:

```
pmi action suspend
```

and

```
pmi action hibernate
```

This requires that you install the powermanagement-interface package (not tested).

`sudo apt-get install powermanagement-interface`

I have also found the commands `sudo pm-suspend` and `sudo pm-hibernate` to work on my netbook.

Comment: pm-suspend and pm-hibernate works for me and it's easy. Requires sudo but that's OK.  
(Found pmi idea before but installing a package to use suspend is well bad...)

Comment: added sudo to the description

Comment: Note that you have to `apt-get install powermanagement-interface` to run pmi.

Comment: On 11.10 only pm-* works, also with powermanagament-interface added

Comment: doesn't work with my ubuntu 12.10. after `apt-get install powermanagement-interface`

Comment: *new method* is now broken see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153099/debian-jessie-cannot-suspend-anymore

Comment: `sudo pm-hibernate` is amazing for making SATA drives really hotplug! :)

Comment: `sudo pm-suspend` works well but while waking up after doing so doesn't ask me for password. what should I do.

Comment: none of the above works, even with sudo rights. not the `pm-hibernate`, `pmi action hibernate`, not the `dbus` stuff. I am sad.

Comment: I'm on 16.04 and both `systemctl suspend` and `pm-suspend` work; the difference being that the latter does not first lock the screen and requires `sudo` to run.

Comment: systemctl suspend -i
It required the -i flag for me on ubuntu 18.04

Comment: To suspend after one hour: `sleep 3600 && systemctl suspend`

Comment: `systemctl suspend` worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, although it made me type my password twice.

Comment: `systemctl hibernate` doesn't work for me. I have Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS on Lenovo-Z50-70.

Comment: Doesn't work on my 21.10 OS. Even when root, and executed locally: `Unit suspend.target is masked.`

Comment: `systemctl hibernate` worked for me in `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS` **BUT**, while hibernating, the screen seemed to freeze, and also the fans when turning it on where insanely loud for at least 10 seconds... I am not sure why.

Comment: Both of `systemctl suspend`  and `systemctl hibernate` work well on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: Why the `Systemd Method` header when the method is `systemctl` instead? They are not the same. Perhaps still good to have that header for search hits, though.

Comment: This answer get confusing at section 3: the new obsolete section. Is the new method obsolete?

Comment: I had to use `sudo`, as in: `sudo systemctl suspend` for it to work.

Comment: Any idea how `sudo systemctl suspend` differs from my `sudo true && gnome-screensaver-command -l && sudo pm-suspend` command [in my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1485370/327339)? Do they have any different side effects or nuances you are aware of?

Answer (score 193):

The gnome-friendly way is to use dbus.

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower \
    org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

There are two advantages to this command over `pm-suspend`.

1. It will lock your screen (upon resume) if you have that option selected in gnome.
2. It does not require root privilege, so it is easy to add it as a keyboard shortcut, for example.

As mentioned in the comments exchanging the `Suspend` in the last line to `Hibernate` creates a hibernate command:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply \
    --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
    /org/freedesktop/UPower \
    org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate
```

If the hibernation throws `Error org.freedesktop.UPower.GeneralError: not authorized` your user might not be allowed to hibernate. Edit or create `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` so it contains the following section: [(source)](http://blog.roland-kluge.de/?p=793)

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

This was tested on [UbuntuGnome 14.04](http://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-14-04-lts-is-released/).

Note: This is basically the same as qbi's answer, but updated to work for newer versions of Ubuntu as well as including hibernate.

Comment: Your answer really should be first. It's non-root no-packages-to-be-installed gnome way of doing it. Like!

Comment: That's the right answer! :D

Comment: AFAIK there is another advantage: It allows other program to detect that suspend/resume happened and act accordingly (for example an IM to resume a network connection to a server).

Comment: While this is actually the right way to do it (tm), SSH users should take note of : http://askubuntu.com/questions/21586/how-can-i-configure-dbus-to-allow-ssh-user-to-suspend-server

Comment: To `Hibernate`, you can simply replace the last line with `org.freedesktop.UPower.Hibernate`

Comment: This works under KDE too, except it doesn't lock the screen. [You can do that with `qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock`.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61339/what-is-the-screen-locking-mechanism-under-kde/119299#119299)

Comment: Under 13.10 I get `Error org.freedesktop.UPower.GeneralError: not authorized`

Comment: on my 13.10 it does work. however, the screen is *not* locked upon resume, even though in "Security and Privacy", "Require my password when waking from Suspend" *is* activated.

Comment: This may be gnome friendly but I can still tell (i.e. wifi/ethernet notification and no graphic glitch) it's not the same clean result than when I do it through the Unity GUI or in the case of my laptop through a hardware suspend button.

Comment: Didn't work for me (Gnome 3.12, Ubuntu 14.04). Seems the [UPower.Suspend] interface was removed, according to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/554899

Comment: Suspend interface was moved to logind; http://askubuntu.com/questions/652978/

Comment: This did work for me under 14.04 Trusty, but just moved to 15.10 Wily and it no longer works.

Comment: firstly, screen locking is not done, and secondly, after each hibernate-resume, the wifi laggs about every other minute. totally unusable for me.

Comment: Please evaluate if this gnome-friendly method is not superceded by 'the new command of systemd' as indicated in (https://askubuntu.com/questions/777178/suspend-command-in-ubuntu-16-04)

Comment: This didn't work for me under Gnome+i3wm in 18.04

Comment: `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method “Suspend”` KDE on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

Answer (score 67):

If you want your computer to suspend in one hour because you want to go to bed listening to your favorite radio station, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo bash -c "sleep 1h; pm-suspend"
```

and your computer will fall asleep in 1 hour. When you awake, it will have kept your open images and all your stuff.

You can replace `1h` by what you want: `h` for hours, `m` for minutes, `s` for seconds, `d` for days.

Comment: That's my use case I'm looking for! AFIK pm-* can be run without superuser permissions

Comment: evidently, this solution needs the `pm-utils` suite: `apt-get install -y pm-utils` :-)

Answer (score 37):

To get Hibernation:

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

To get Suspend:

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

Comment: "sudo pm-suspend" not working on mint 13 mate :(

Comment: Yeah I think that package was not installed . look for those packages in synaptic.

Comment: the package is installed, I think 'mate-power-manager' is interfering with it.

Comment: Perfect, thanks the pm-suspend was exactly what I was after without having to install all the X related junk with the powermanagement-interface package. All that's needed to use pm-* is the the pm-utils package.

Comment: The drawback of this method is that if you are using the GUI, pm-suspend will NOT block your session, which can be insecure.

Comment: It works on ubuntu 15.10, too.

Comment: works on 14.04 lts

Comment: Works on 20.04 too :)

Comment: Recent debian today (2024), I believe pm-suspend is the best what we have.

Answer (score 28):

You can use the file `/sys/power/state` to do this. First find out what states are supported:

```
user@linux:_> cat /sys/power/state
standby mem disk

root@linux:~> echo -n mem > /sys/power/state  # suspend to ram
root@linux:~> echo -n disk > /sys/power/state  # suspend to disk
```

or via dbus:

<del># Suspend
    dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.PowerManager \
      --type=method_call --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 \ 
      /org/gnome/PowerManager org.gnome.PowerManager.Suspend

    #Hibernate
    dbus-send --session --dest=org.gnome.PowerManager \
      --type=method_call --print-reply --reply-timeout=2000 \ 
      /org/gnome/PowerManager org.gnome.PowerManager.Hibernate</del>

According to this [entry in launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-power-manager/+bug/554899) the above interface was removed. So it would not work anymore in Ubuntu.

Comment: First idea gives me: "bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument"
    
Dbus idea gives output: "Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Suspend" with signature "" on interface "org.gnome.PowerManager" doesn't exist"

Comment: I added a small explanation to the `/sys/power/state`-thing. Furthermore the dbus method was removed from Ubuntu so it won't work anymore.

Comment: `$ sudo echo -n mem > /sys/power/state` - `bash: /sys/power/state: Permission denied`

Comment: This works great. For people having problems with this method when using sudo, the "pipe to file", aka ">" is running in your current shell, so it doesn't get super user privileges while your echo did. You'll need to use `sudo -i` first, or pipe to `sudo tee` like so: `echo mem | sudo tee /sys/power/state`

Answer (score 14):

since **15.04** systemD is the standard init system so there is a new command to be used:

```
systemctl suspend
```

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu 15.04. The command `systemctl suspend` does suspend the computer, but it does not cause the screen to be locked, even though I've checked the "Lock screen when system is going for sleep" checkbox in Settings -> Power Manager -> Security. Anyone have any idea why?

Comment: I've upgraded to Xubuntu 16.04. The command `systemctl suspend` still suspends the computer. Now, it also causes the screen to be locked, if and only if the "Lock screen when system is going for sleep" checkbox in Settings -> Power Manager -> Security is checked.

Answer (score 13):

To suspend a system (14.04) from the command line (or keyboard shortcut) use:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.login1" /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend boolean:true
```

I found this out by playing around with gdbus which can list the interfaces available:

To list the services available on the bus:

```
dbus-send --system --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus --type=method_call --print-reply /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListNames
```

To find the methods:

```
gdbus introspect --system --dest org.freedesktop.login1 --object-path /org/freedesktop/login1 --recurse
```

Answer (score 8):

Adam Paetznick's dbus-send answer didn't work as purported for me on lucid; the machine woke up unlocked, even though the gnome-power-manager is set to lock the screen on wake-up.
I want the screen to be locked at wake-up, and found that the following does that:

```
$ gnome-screensaver-command --lock && pmi action hibernate
```

I imagine this does not depend on the gnome configuration, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: Nice. Or `xscreensaver-command --lock` as the case may be.

Answer (score 4):

**New interface**

…which works in 15.10 Wily, and possibly Utopic and Vivid.

```
dbus-send --print-reply --system                         \
    --dest=org.freedesktop.login1                        \
    /org/freedesktop/login1                              \
    org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend boolean:true
```

Helpfully this doesn't require sudo, unlike the `pm-suspend` command.

Comment: My XPS 13 9350 with Debian/Gnome was with suspend/hibernate issues when closing the lid. After running this command (and the equivalent for hibernation), it went successfully into suspension (and hibernation) and now closing and opening the lid work as expected!

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to put a remote machine in standby over ssh:

```
ssh -t 192.168.1.4 'sudo nohup &>/dev/null bash -c "(sleep 1; echo -n mem >/sys/power/state) &"'
x@192.168.1.4's password: 
[sudo] password for x: 
Connection to 192.168.1.4 closed.
```

/sys/power/state works in Ubuntu 13.10. pmi gives Dbus error.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I've been experimenting with the pmi method. However, when I tried this, I got an error message: `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.ChildExited: Launch helper exited with unknown return code 1`. However, there is a workaround in the [3rd comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powermanagement-interface/+bug/1176829/comments/3) of [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/powermanagement-interface/+bug/1176829), which seems to have worked for me (I'm using Ubuntu 13.03).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Update for those who, like me, still work on KDE/Ubuntu 14.04 systems. To lock use `qdbus`, and to suspend use `dbus`. Full command:

```
qdbus org.freedesktop.ScreenSaver /ScreenSaver Lock && dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

To hibernate, i.e. suspend to harddisk instead of RAM, replace 'Suspend' at the end of the command by 'Hibernate'.

To just lock the screen without suspending, `xscreensaver-command -lock` will work, IF you type only 1 hyphen for the '-lock' option, and only if the screensaver is running. Actually not a very useful command. Using `i3lock` is easier, but then you will not get a neat login dialog to get back to work, as you will when using `qdbus`.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me on 16.04 (with Gnome desktop):

`gnome-screensaver-command --lock && compsleep`

I have also installed it as a custom keyboard shortcut via the Gnome settings panel as keys "Shift-Super-X".

Answer (score 0):

**How to lock the screen and put the computer to sleep (suspend) in a 1-liner from the command line (could be assigned to an Ubuntu shortcut key)**

*Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.*

This is directly [from my longer answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474754/327339). Refer to that answer for a detailed explanation of this command:

> You can lock the screen and put the computer to sleep in a single command like this:
>
> ```bash
> # lock the screen and put the computer to sleep
> sudo true && gnome-screensaver-command -l && sudo pm-suspend
> ```
>
> You can assign the above command to a shortcut key if you want to quickly put your computer to sleep.

`sudo systemctl suspend`, as [shown in the main answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1795/327339), also seems to produce a similar result to my `sudo true && gnome-screensaver-command -l && sudo pm-suspend` command. I don't know how they differ or if they have any different effects.

Update: on older versions of Ubuntu, it's possible that `sudo systemctl suspend` will *not* also lock the screen and require a password upon waking up, whereas my `sudo true && gnome-screensaver-command -l && sudo pm-suspend` command *will* always lock the screen first and require a password after wake-up. On Ubuntu 22.04 though, the results seem to be the same. In the Edge Browser only (using any other browser won't show the full content), you can see [a chat I had with Bing AI about this here](https://sl.bing.net/eMhe7aadyCW).

After waking up from sleep (suspend), you can run `journalctl -n 1000 -e | grep "PM: suspend"` to prove your computer really was asleep. Again, see [my longer answer on this](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474754/327339) for details.

Via the GUI menus:

Running my command above produces the exact same result as clicking the top-right of your screen and going to "Power Off/Log Out" --> Suspend, as shown in this screenshot here:

[image]