# How do I lock the desktop screen via command line?

Tags: command-line, lock-screen

How can I lock my desktop screen from the command line?

Comment: For newer versions of Ubuntu, you can try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/457204/how-can-i-lock-the-screen-using-the-new-lockscreen-from-the-command-line

Comment: Related: [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1792/327339)

Answer (score 86, accepted):

You can lock the computer by running `gnome-screensaver-command` with the `-l` flag like so:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

However this will only work if you have Gnome Screensaver running for your session (should be - unless you've disabled it) you can start that from the commandline with:

```
gnome-screensaver
```

Comment: `cinnamon-screensaver-command -l` for cinnamon! ;))

Comment: Likewise, use `mate-screensaver-command -l` for MATE desktop.

Answer (score 51):

In newer versions of GNOME 3, `gnome-screensaver` is no more.

The generic solution seems to be

```
xdg-screensaver lock
```

You also can call dbus directly instead ([source](https://pgaskin.net/linux-tip/lock-screen-from-command-line/)):

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

It also seems they have taken away the possibility to *un*lock the screen from the command line.

Comment: yes. very good answer. one command to rule them all ! :-)

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for in 2019.

Comment: `xdg-screensaver lock` works for me in Mate Desktop on FreeBSD

Comment: @xliiv, same command works for `sddm` in Kubuntu too.

Answer (score 29):

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

If you're in a different (desktop) session (e.g. virtual console, switched to another login, SSH), specify the display explicitly (`:0` is the default display):

```
DISPLAY=:0 gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

To unlock, use the `-d` (`--deactivate`) option.

Comment: can you clarify me the DISPALY=:0 option?

Comment: Sorry for my English...

DISPLAY is a variable and define in which display an X Window System program renders to (it can be another monitor).
In TTY this variable is empty.
By default, first display is ":0.0".
So use DISPLAY=:x before your command, indicates in which display run the command. And use DISPLAY=:0 or DISPLAY=:0.0 indicates: run the program in the first display.

Comment: @RenjithG this is quite clear if you think about it, also please do not be rude to the author of the previous comment.

Comment: This works perfect, thx! Now I can add a keyboard shortcut to fix my broken lock screen command.

Answer (score 18):

`gnome-screensaver-command --lock` will do it.

Answer (score 6):

Under KDE `dm-tool lock` will work (for me on Kubuntu 15.04).

Comment: This is the solution when using lightdm.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a long way of accomplishing it (adding a quicker way below):**

to make it even easier to lock, you can add an executable script to an executable path, call it "lock" and then the locking of your screen will be as easy as typing "lock" in cli

Here's how to do it:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

`vim ~/bin/lock`

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

save and quit

```
chmod +x ~/bin/lock
```

don't forget to add ~/bin to your ~/.profile - note the dot at the beginning of the file name
one word of caution about this, make sure you add it to the right file. Here is what the .profile says about it:

```
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
```

therefore you want to first check if the above-mentioned files exist in your home directory, you should add it there, if they don't exist, then add the path to bin to the .profile

```
vim ~/.profile # or one of the the other files if they exist
```

append the following at the end:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

at this point you can launch the following shortcut from cli

```
you@yourUbuntu:~$ lock
```

**[EDIT] Here is the quick and easy way to do it:**
add an alias to your ~/.bashrc file, which is executed every time a shell is opened, thus ensuring Alias persists:

```
vim ~/.bashrc
# set lockscreen
alias lock="gnome-screensaver-command -l"
```

the result is the same, but quicker

Answer (score 0):

There are also many minimalistic utilities that really **only lock**, they don't do anything else.  (This can be more secure as in general keeping software simple leads to less bugs.)

For example:

- [*slock*](http://tools.suckless.org/slock/)
- [*i3lock*](https://i3wm.org/i3lock/)