# Ubuntu 13.04 not locking screen

Tags: 13.04, lock-screen

I might have uninstalled some packages I shouldn't. For now, the only thing I've been missing is the lock screen. When I press Ctrl + Alt + L, or press the "Lock" button on the shutdown menu or I press the turn-off button and select "lock" nothing happens.

Do you guys have any ideas on what I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Keyboard shortcut for Lockscreen not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126782/keyboard-shortcut-for-lockscreen-not-working)

Comment: Nope. In my case, none of the ways lock the screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install gnome-screensaver

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-screensaver
```

Comment: I was pretty sure I checked that gnome-screensaver was there.. But it worked.. Odd.. Thank you :)

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/184728/how-do-i-lock-the-screen-from-a-terminal/