# How to lock the screen in XUbuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, lock-screen

I've been trying to figure out how to lock the screen in XUbuntu 16.04 and I can't seem to make anything work.  Various posts suggest using the settings under 'Power Manager' and 'Light Locker Settings', which have selectors to enable and disable the screensaver, and I've tried all possible combinations of them, but none of them do anything.

Other places suggest running `xflock4` or hitting `ctrl-alt-del` (which on the keyboard shortcuts runs xflock4), but that also does nothing.  There's also no documentation for `xflock4` (man xflock4 says "No manual entry" and `xflock4 --help` does nothing.)

**Update**

After poking around things for awhile, I fould `dm-tool` which has a `lock` option.  Running `dm-tool lock` from a terminal successfully locks the screen.  I can also set the keyboard shortcuts to make ctrl-alt-del run `dm-tool lock`, so I can now lock the screen with a key combo.

However, I still can't figure out how to get it to lock the screen after a timeout...

[image]


  [image]


  [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the default Xubuntu setup:

- light-locker is set to autostart because it must be running in the background to work
- Keyboard shortcuts for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> are configured that call `xflock4`
- `xflock4` calls light-locker to lock the screen

If you run `xflock4` in a terminal and nothing happens, odds are light-locker isn't running. The solution more or less is to restore the default settings:

1. Remove light-locker-settings package. It's not necessary because screen lock settings are handled by Xfce Power Manager (as you can see in the screenshot you posted)

   ```
   sudo apt remove light-locker-settings
   ```
2. Make sure essential packages are installed (just to be safe)

   ```
   sudo apt install light-locker xfce4-power-manager xfce4-session
   ```
3. Reset light-locker settings

   ```
   sudo dpkg-reconfigure light-locker
   ```
4. Remove any autostart overrides

   ```
   rm ~/.config/autostart/light-locker.desktop
   ```

   (This can be removed because the light-locker package installs a default autostart file here: /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop)
5. Reset the LockCommand setting in case it's been overrriden

   ```
   xfconf-query -c xfce4-session -p /general/LockCommand -r
   ```

   ([`xflock4` is just a shell script](https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/tree/scripts/xflock4) that will first look at LockCommand to see what command to run, falling back to light-locker if it isn't set)
6. Reset keyboard shortcuts

   - If you're not worried about losing any other custom keyboard shortcuts, you can just reset them all to default:

     ```
     xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p / -rR
     ```
   - Otherwise, these are the specific keyboard shortcuts Xubuntu sets by default for screen locking:

     ```
     xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p "/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>Delete" -s "xflock4" -n -t string
     xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p "/commands/custom/<Primary><Alt>l" -s "xflock4" -n -t string
     xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p "/commands/default/<Primary><Alt>Delete" -s "xflock4" -n -t string
     xfconf-query -c xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts -p "/commands/default/<Primary><Alt>l" -s "xflock4" -n -t string
     ```
7. Log out and log back in. This will make sure light-locker autostart is working and also may be necessary for the keyboard shortcuts to refresh.
8. Make sure light-locker is running

   ```
   $ ps -e | grep light-locker
    1869 ?        00:00:00 light-locker
   ```
9. Make sure `xflock4` locks the screen

   ```
   xflock4
   ```
10. Make sure the keyboard shortcuts to lock the screen work

    - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>
    - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
11. Lastly, if you want the screen to automatically lock after a certain time

    1. Open the menu > *Settings* > *Power Manager* > *Security*
    2. *Automatically lock the session* > *When the screensaver is activated*
    3. If you want to have a real screensaver, you'll need to install and configure `xscreensaver` or `gnome-screensaver`. Otherwise if you're okay with a blank screen, go to the *Display* tab in Power Manager and adjust the times as desired

Comment: Thank you very much. This was very helpful especially step 11. Because it describes the relation between security and display settings. I was confused about the "When screensaver is acivated" and there is no screensaver installed. But when realizing that black sreen on display tab is meant by that all made sense to me. :-)

Comment: @sjuk It's actually much simpler than it seems! `xflock4` is just a shell script that will first try the command set in LockCommand (in newer versions), then xscreensaver, then light-locker, then gnome-screensaver: https://git.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-session/tree/scripts/xflock4

Answer (score 2):

To lock the screen in *xubuntu*:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

Note: The time os the button matters, try it several times to get it right.

Image: see line `xflock4  Ctrl+Alt+L`

[image]

Comment: No effect.  The keyboard display on my machine only shows Ctrl+Alt+Delete for xlock4 (which also has no effect)

Comment: please post an image if possible...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `xautolock` to lock after a timeout.
Or `xss-lock` to lock when lid is closed and when the "blank after" timeout expires.