# Keyboard shortcut for Lockscreen not working properly

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, lock-screen

This question is different from [Keyboard shortcut for Lockscreen not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126782/keyboard-shortcut-for-lockscreen-not-working).

Ubuntu version: 18.10.

In **Settings** > **Devices** > **Keyboard**, lock screen is set to <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (aka <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>).

*As a user, when I press the lock screen shortcut, I want the screen to be locked and all currently running applications to be out of view, so that anyone else cannot view my screen when I am away from my computer.*

**Expected result**

- All running applications disappear from view and are replaced with a lock screen (either a screensaver or a login screen).
- All keyboard input is restricted to the password field of the login screen.
- All mouse input is restricted to login fields, and to the icons in the top right of the screen (accessibility, network, power off).

**Actual result**

- All running applications are still visible
- The computer does not appear to respond to keyboard input

  - I cannot type anything in a running terminal that was in focus
  - I cannot <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> to another application.
- I can move the mouse, but reaction to mouse input is restricted to the icons in the top right.

  - When I click on one of the items, it appears as if there are 2 identical dropdowns overlayed, with a few pixels off, and the view switches between them, so it looks like there is a ghost image.

**Workaround**

- Pressing <kbd>SUPER</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, followed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, turns the screen black.
- When I move the mouse, the screen turns on, and I see the lock screen.

Comment: May be a hardware issue related to hibernate. On my system, the screen blanks *and* the system attempts (and actually goes) to sleep modus. What you see may result from sleep not properly working on your hardware.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How would I be able to test that? Any specific commands I can run to verify hibernate/sleep?

Comment: `systemctl suspend -i` is the command to turn the system to sleep state.

Comment: In backsight, sleep will not be the issue. I tested locking on my system a bit better: the system does not go in sleep state. Monitor is physically turned off, though, so still there might be the issue with your monitor.

Comment: When I run `systemctl suspend -i`, the screen blanks.

Comment: I have 2 monitors, one on DVI and the other on HDMI.

Comment: Disconnect one, see whether the issue persists.