# 2022: Keyboard Shortcut for Lock Screen just stopped working

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

This is a related, older question that isn't what this post is about: [Keyboard shortcut for "Lock screen" not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126782/keyboard-shortcut-for-lock-screen-not-working#)

My question is different. For the past year or more, I've had no problem locking my screen with `Super+L`. You can see in my settings that the shortcut is still enabled:

[image]

However, I recently installed some Ubuntu-recommended update and the `Super+L` shortcut now no longer works. I don't know what exactly was updated. Does anyone know how to either (a) get my lock keyboard shortcut working again, or (b) hunt down the update that broke it?

I'm specifically using:

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit: Now my machine no longer locks when I shut the lid. What is happening?