# Set a password, yet it logs in without one

Tags: login, password, login-screen

My account is an administrator; I'm using Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

I've set a password and set automatic login to <kbd>OFF</kbd>, yet when I wake up from suspension or reboot if I just press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or type in anything then it logs me in.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Have you checked power options? It usually has an option to the effect of "Lock when going for suspend" It differs between dekstop environments I think

Comment: I don't have option, all I have is when lid is closed, when power is critical and when computer is inactive.

Comment: Do you have any screensavers installed such as `xscreensaver`?

Comment: @Organic Marble - xscreensaver is not installed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Easy:

- Click the gear icon in the top-right corner of your screen:

  [image: Gear icon]
- Click <kbd>System Settings</kbd>, then <kbd>Brightness & Lock</kbd>:

  [image: Brightness&Lock screen]
- Click the <kbd>Lock</kbd> switch until it goes into the <kbd>On</kbd> position and ensure the <kbd>Require my password when waking from suspend</kbd> is ticked.

### Done! ;-)

---

#### If that doesn't work:

Create a new user on your system and see whether that user does work.  If that's the case (in the below example we'll use `steam-gamer` and `steam-gamer2`), just do the following:

1. Open the file manager
2. Browse to the `/home/steam-gamer` directory
3. **Copy** (don't move!) all the *files* from `Downloads` to `/home/steam-gamer2/Downloads`
4. Check you did a good job.
5. Now delete `/home/steam-gamer/Downloads`
6. Go back to step 3 and repeat for `Documents`, `Videos`, ...
7. **After a couple of days** to allow you to ensure you didn't forget to copy anything, just *delete `steam-gamer` together with it's home directory* by issuing the following command:

   ```
   sudo deluser steam-gamer --remove-home
   ```

Comment: Oh, and you know the drill by now... Don't thank me!  If this answer did help, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like the answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like the answer, click on the little grey ☑ *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, just [ask another one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask)!
 **;-)**

Comment: The lock switch is turned on,and checked 'Require my password when waking from suspend' but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @Steamgamer That is usually rare or intermittent, but is a well-known bug: See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/1027902 for example.

Answer (score 3):

I like using the terminal:

1. Enable Screen Lock

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled true
   ```
2. Enable Lock on Suspend

   ```
   gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver ubuntu-lock-on-suspend true
   ```

---

To disable, use `false` instead of `true`.

**;-)**

Answer (score 2):

First make sure you have all the security updates installed. If this is not the issue, check if the problem appears when you log into other graphical environments. You can also test the manual lock with  "Ctrl + Alt + L". If you use a screen saver, take a look at [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459840/lock-screen-not-working-14-04).

Answer (score -1):

The brute force approach is to hand edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, adding a `#` character to the beginning of every line starting with `autologin`.

Comment: This is what is in the config file: `[SeatDefaults] autologin-user=`, only 1 line...

Comment: Maybe changing that line to just be `[SeatDefaults]` makes a difference, then?

Comment: Rönnquis, that also didn't work, but thanks for contributing.