# lockscreen not available Ubuntu 20.04.2

Tags: lock-screen, gdm, screensaver

My look screen is not working or even "not presented".
After reboot I can unlock the device but after that I cant lock it anymore

`Super + L` not working

`gnome-screensaver-command -l` not working, but I get

> ** (gnome-screensaver-command:6363): WARNING **: 10:22:19.218: unable to send message: Zeitüberschreitung wurde erreicht
> ** Message: 10:22:19.220: Did not receive a reply from the screensaver.

Auto lockscreen not working, although configured

[image: Auto lockscreen not working]

I cant even choose a lockscreen image...

[image: Lockscreen image]

Whats that?

Comment: can you check result with this command once `gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen`  if true, then make it false like `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 18.04 refuses to use lock screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073339/ubuntu-18-04-refuses-to-use-lock-screen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You check result with this command once

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen
```

if result is `true`, then make it `false` like

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/a/1080543/349837).