# How can I configure dbus to allow ssh-user to suspend server?

Tags: ssh, dbus

I try to suspend my server using dbus and UPower. The server runs Ubuntu LucidLynx 64bit.

While everything works fine if I am sitting directly at the machine, it won't work via ssh. 
If I connect to the server via ssh and try to suspend the machine using dbus and upower, it gives back

dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.UPower.GeneralError: not authorized

Could anyone please tell me how to configure dbus in order to allow ssh-users to suspend the machine?

Comment: btw: I DO grep and use the current dbus-session-adress...

Comment: Can you give some details on the method you're using? What command line, tools, etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two basic ways this can be done and a workaround:

Either you need to modify `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy`, set the `XDG_SESSION_COOKIE` environment variable to the appropriate value or use `pm-suspend`:

#### Modifying `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy`

Apply this patch:

```
--- /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy.orig  2011-11-16 19:06:59.274055248 +0100
+++ /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.upower.policy   2011-11-16 19:11:15.178864922 +0100
@@ -21,6 +21,7 @@
     <defaults>
       <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
       <allow_active>yes</allow_active>
+      <allow_any>yes</allow_any>
     </defaults>
   </action>
```

(To the `<action id="org.freedesktop.upower.suspend">` tag/section), and it'll work too...

or

#### `XDG_SESSION_COOKIE`

When you're using the desktop, you'll see that `$XDG_SESSION_COOKIE` has one value, but in an ssh session, it has another. Store `XDG_SESSION_COOKIE` e.g. in a .dotfile or something when the desktop starts and source it in your script that needs to do it over ssh.

#### pm-suspend

Or you could just give up on doing it with `dbus` and `UPower` and just issue `pm-suspend` as root and get it over with! :-)

Comment: +1 for "just issue pm-suspend as root and get it over with!" - available from the pm-utils package.

Answer (score 5):

Files under `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions` are not meant to be modified.

Create a file named `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/allow_all_ssh-users_to_upower.pkla`

```
[Allow all ssh-users to upower]
Identity=unix-group:ssh-users
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.policy
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=yes
AllowAny=yes
```

Comment: There is a typo in the answer - the last line should say `ResultAny`, not `AllowAny`.