# Suspending Ubuntu using terminal

Tags: command-line, suspend

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line)

How can I suspend Ubuntu using the terminal? Can I schedule it to "wake up"?

Another thing that I wanted to know is whether processes like downloads continue to run when Ubuntu is suspended?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question: No, downloads and such don't continue while the computer is suspended. In fact, the network is brought down. Nothing continues. The only difference between suspension and hibernation is that during suspend, enough power is used to maintain everything in RAM.