# What is the package name of the lock screen?

Tags: package-management, lock-screen

After reading a review of the Ubuntu Developer Summit which said that one of the proposed changes in 12.10 would be to use LightDM as the lock screen:

> LightDM will be implemented as the lock-screen, thus adding visual and
>   behavioural consistency to the desktop. [Source](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/05/uds-q-summary-bye-bye-unity-2d-hello-gnome-shell-spin/)

I was wondering what is the package name of the current lock-screen, or is it a part of the unity package?

As clarification it is this screen I am referring to:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package providing the lock screen is `gnome-screensaver`.

Read more about it here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingScreenLocking/HowScreenLockingWorks

Answer (score 1):

Check [What is the screen locking mechanism under KDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61339/what-is-the-screen-locking-mechanism-under-kde/119299#119299). It describes how you can figure it out. Although the examples in the answer are KDE based, there are notes how you can make it work for Gnome too.