# How can I hibernate/suspend from the command line and do so at a specific time

Tags: 11.10, command-line, suspend, hibernate

I managed to find out how to suspend/hibernate the system from the command line by reading [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line).

However, I would like to know how to use the command line to suspend/hibernate at a given time, in absolute (example, 11PM) or relative (example, in 30 minutes) terms.

I already know how to do this with shutdown, but I'm note sure if the command is similar.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use the [`at`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/cgi-bin/search.py?q=at&op=&cx=003883529982892832976:5zl6o8w6f0s&cof=FORID:9&ie=UTF-8&siteurl=manpages.ubuntu.com/) command to schedule any action, including running the commands detailed in [that question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line).

For example, if you want to hibernate in 30 minutes:

`echo 'pmi action hibernate' | at now + 30 min`

Or if you want to suspend at 11:00 pm:

`echo 'pmi action suspend' | at 11pm`

If you need to run a command as `root`, run `at` with `sudo` rather than the command itself with `sudo` (since `sudo` should only be run interactively, unless you've configured it not to ask for your password). For example, the equivalents of the above commands using `pm-hibernate` and `pm-suspend` are:

`echo pm-hibernate | sudo at now + 30 min`

`echo pm-suspend | sudo at 11pm`

Comment: Thanks for catching that both situations were asked for... I edited the title to reflect this as well. I modified my answer to include both situations now.

Comment: Any idea how I can clear the jobs?

Comment: @Rexford The [`atrm` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/atrm.1.html) removes jobs created by `at`.

Answer (score 15):

For relative specification (e.g. "after 30 minutes") you can simply use `sleep` command to make suspending/hibernating command wait.

---

#### Examples:

Wait 30 minutes, then suspend:

```
sudo sleep 30m; sudo pm-suspend
```

Wait 1 hour, then hibernate:

```
sudo sleep 1h; sudo pm-hibernate
```

Comment: I like this approach too.

Comment: After 1h `pm-hibernate` want a password for root again and suspend does not happen.

Comment: how about logging in as root to avoid getting asked for a password?

Comment: Or try something like `sudo "sleep 1h; pm-hibernate"`, that way there's no second call to sudo.

Answer (score 5):

For specific times repeated - like shutting down computers are a specific time each day. use cron.

```
crontab -e
```

add the following:

```
15 14 1 * * pmi action suspend
```

If you want to customize it.

```
* * * * * command to be executed
- - - - -
| | | | |
| | | | ----- Day of week (0 - 7) (Sunday=0 or 7)
| | | ------- Month (1 - 12)
| | --------- Day of month (1 - 31)
| ----------- Hour (0 - 23)
------------- Minute (0 - 59)
```

For a one time job us the at command

For example, if you want to hibernate in 30 minutes:

```
echo 'pmi action hibernate' | at now + 30 min
```

Or if you want to suspend at 11:00 pm:

```
echo 'pmi action suspend' | at 11pm
```

Comment: Using `cron` is a good solution when the goal is to suspend or hibernate at a specific time of day, or a specific time on a specific day of the week, or month, or year. But for scheduling a single suspension or hibernation, which seems to be what [Ederico](http://askubuntu.com/users/28661/ederico) was asking about (and which is something that makes a lot more sense to want to do), the `at` command should be used. (You can schedule a single event with `cron` by making the event edit the relevant crontab, for example using `sed` or `awk`, but that's extremely complex and unnecessary; use `at`.)

Comment: Does not fit to the relative terms requested by the question, its only useful for specific schedules.

Comment: Yes, this was an example for the 'specific time' that was requested. "However, I would like to know how to use the command line to suspend/hibernate at a given time, in absolute (example, 11PM)"

Comment: You've edited your answer to add information about how to use `at`, but the information you have added is unfortunately not correct. The `<` operator redirects text from the *file* or *device* specified to its right to standard input for the command specified to its left. If you wanted to use `<` instead of `|` (as in [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/78907/how-can-i-hibernate-suspend-from-the-command-line-and-do-so-at-a-specific-time-a/78927#78927)), you'd have to make a file with `pmi action suspend` (or `pmi action hibernate`) as its contents. Such complexity makes `|` better here.

Comment: As a general guideline, when you have a `cat` command to the left of a `|` (e.g. `cat foo | bar`), you can replace that with a `<` expression (`bar < foo`). But when you have an `echo` command to the left of a `|`, that cannot be trivially replaced with a `<` expression.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. It should be edited with your examples now. The aksubuntu team can consolidate this and make it useful for future folks searching.