# equivalent of command line 'shutdown -h +60' but for suspend to RAM?

Tags: 11.10, shutdown, suspend, timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hibernate/suspend from the command line and do so at a specific time and a relative time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78907/how-can-i-hibernate-suspend-from-the-command-line-and-do-so-at-a-specific-time-a)

what is the equivalent of a command line like 'shutdown -h +60' but for suspend to RAM? I would like to be able to send the laptop to suspend with a time delay, but I don't know of the equivalent for it in a terminal command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The already present response has two options, in Ubuntu 11.10 you use this one:

```
# echo 'pm-suspend' | at now + 60 min
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [already answered](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78907/how-can-i-hibernate-suspend-from-the-command-line-and-do-so-at-a-specific-time-a) on askubuntu.

Short story, something along the lines of:

`sleep <time in seconds> && pmi action hibernate` as `root`

or equivalent using `at` would do it.