# Screen not locked after suspen (run from terminal)

Tags: suspend, lock-screen

I have just  found a answer to my question "[How can I hibernate/suspend from the command line and do so at a specific time and a relative time?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/78907/how-can-i-hibernate-suspend-from-the-command-line-and-do-so-at-a-specific-time-a)".

The thing though is that on many occasions the resume is back with an unlocked screen!

It's not always, but most of the time. Why & how can I make sure it locks?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you sure that the computer is suspended, or could it have just switched off the display? I think ubuntu does the latter by default after a certain time (maybe 10 minutes?), you can see the setting (in 12.04) from `System settings > Brightness and Lock`.

Comment: I don't think so. It happened a number of times. moreover, I recall once I closed the lid after it suspended & the lights started blinking (a sign of suspend).
I'll consider your answer & check it next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I haven't faced this problem since I posted here. I guess it was just my mistake.

The screen does lock; I might have made a mistake like "taneli" said above!