# How to suspend from command line such that screen is locked?

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, suspend, lock-screen

I'm using Xubuntu 12.04. In the Power Manager, I have checked Extended -> Lock screen when going for suspend/hibernate. If I choose to suspend from the main menu / Panel 1, the screen is locked. However, if I use `dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend` (see [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line); I use this command via a keyboard shortcut), the screen is *not* locked. How can I (1) suspend the system (2) have the screen locked at the same time (3) do not require root rights to do so [since I would like the command to be assigned to a keyboard shortcut].

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that by using the following:

```
gnome-screensaver-command --lock && dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

In a keyboard shortcut you need to put `sh -c "<command>"` replacing `<command>` with the command above, like:

```
sh -c "gnome-screensaver-command --lock && dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend"
```

If the above command does not work, you can also try using a shell script file (for example `suspend_lockscreen.sh`). First create the file call the following commands in a console:

```
cd ~
echo "gnome-screensaver-command --lock" >> suspend_lockscreen.sh
echo "dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend" >> suspend_lockscreen.sh
chmod +x suspend_lockscreen.sh
```

That will create a file named suspend_lockscreen.sh in the user home folder. Then, in the shortcut just call: `./suspend_lockscreen.sh`.

*Note: `gnome-screensaver-command` can be replaced by `xscreensaver-command`, as pointed out in one comment.*

Comment: Nope it does only lock the screen and forgets about suspending it  according to a comment made in the answer I made ;)

Comment: Ahh, good. I just realized that `gnome-screensaver-command` can also be replaced by `xscreensaver-command` so no additional installation is required. Without the `&& dbus-send...` part one simply gets a lock (without suspend); with it, one gets a suspend with lock on wake-up. Perfect.

Comment: Unfortunately, the command works from the terminal but not from the keyboard shortcut I defined :-( Do you know what might be the problem?

Comment: @MariusHofert I've updated the answer with how to use the commands from a keyboard shurtcut. See if it works as you need. (I've tested in Ubuntu 12.04 and it worked).

Comment: Still the same problem: locking works; suspending does not (Xubuntu 12.04)

Comment: @MariusHofert You haven't missed out the last quotation marks right?
If you try the second command (sh -c "...") in a console, does it work?

Comment: use a simple locking program like `i3lock` instead.  Given that all it does is lock the screen, I think it should avoid whatever interaction is going on here with the screensaver programs.

Comment: @amfcosta: I haven't forgotten the (last) quotation marks. I even tried with single quotation marks. The funny thing is, it works perfectly fine in the terminal, even without sh -c "...". I'll try the idea with the shell script later. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @amfcosta: Ohh, I'm sorry, I accidentally had "sh-c ..." instead of "sh -c ..." :-( It's working now! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just realized that you can also use `xflock4` instead of `xscreensaver-command --lock`

Answer (score 2):

I was using amfcosta's dbus command to suspend from the command line.  However, upon resume, eth0 was down.

I then found this command:

`xfce4-session-logout --suspend`

This command disables networking, suspends, and then re-enables networking when the computer wakes up.

`xfce4-session-logout` is xfce specific, but other desktop environments may have similar `*-session-logout` commands.

I am running Xubuntu 14.04.

Update: This may not affect others, but it turns out that on my Asus EEE 900, the wired ethernet connection only works every other time the EEE wakes up.  This is, of course, very annoying, and means that suspend is unusable.

Answer (score 1):

With Ubuntu 15.10, this works as well:

```
gnome-screensaver-command --lock && systemctl -i suspend
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: the `xscreensaver-command` only works with option `-lock` (with 1 hyphen, not a double as with the `gnome-screensaver-command`). Yet, the command only works when the screensaver is running, so not very useful.