# Suspend from the command line and show Unity's lock screen in 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, lock-screen

How can I suspend my computer from the command line and, once it wakes up, display Unity's lock screen? I want to replicate **exactly** what happens when I click on the system cog icon at the top right of the Unity panel and go to `Suspend` in Ubuntu 14.04 (**not** an earlier version!).

I've found many answers that do not work, such as those found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138661/how-to-suspend-from-command-line-such-that-screen-is-locked). All of them are for older versions of Ubuntu or invoke either gnome-screensaver or xscreensaver's lock screen.

This command, for instance, suspends the computer, but does not lock the screen:
`dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend`, despite `Require my password when waking from suspend` being checked in the `Brightness & Lock system` settings.

Actually, I don't even know how to invoke Unity's lock screen at all in 14.04: the closest I can come to is `dm-tools lock`, but this is not quite the same, as it allows you to sign in as a different user and shows more indicators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I figured out how to get the 14.04 lock screen, I just chained the dbus lock command with the suspend one:

```
sh -c "dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock && dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.UPower /org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend"
```

Comment: Fabulous and perfectly bindable. I'd been struggling with pm-suspend and gnome-screensaver-command, but this works much better.

Comment: Unfortunately, the suspend signal doesn't work for me. I get `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: Method "Suspend" with signature "" on interface "org.freedesktop.UPower" doesn't exist` in the terminal.