# Ubuntu 16.04, direct to desktop after suspend, bypassing lock screen despite settings

Tags: 16.04, suspend, lock-screen

I'm working on Ubuntu 16.04.  My computer is configured to require a password when waking from suspend in the Brightness & Lock settings.  When I resume from suspend I am taken directly to the desktop, bypassing the lock screen / password prompt.  How can I troubleshoot / fix this issue?

**Edit**

An Ubuntu internal error notice typically pops up when I resume from suspend.  The details of that report indicate that `/usr/bin/compiz` is crashing.  It's hard to say whether this is related to my login bypass issue.

Comment: Maybe https://askubuntu.com/q/138661/367990 contains any helpful workarounds. It doesn't aim at analyzing the cause though.