# What is the command for sleep/hibernate?

Tags: power-management, shutdown, sleep, aspire-one

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line)

I have an Acre Aspire One and this netbook does not have a sleep function on the key board and with the removal of the hibernate option I have been required to resort to shutting my comp down every time. So I know that under 'system settings'>'keyboard'>'shortcuts' I can create a custom key combo but I do not know that the command is of the sleep setting. So, please help.

Thank you

Answer (score 35, accepted):

All of the following commands require root permissions.  The most common way to do this is prefix the command with `sudo`.

**The command for Suspend (Sleep) is `pm-suspend`** (`sudo pm-suspend` etc.)

The command for Hibernate is `pm-hibernate` ***(Note that Hibernation mode is not compatible with all hardware, please test this before using it.)***

The command for the hibrid of them both is `pm-suspend-hybrid`

The hybrid command saves the session to the Hard Disk (safer storage place), but the system will stay running, allowing for faster resume.  This does **not** mean you can turn off your computer and have your session saved.  You will need to use the regular hibernate command for that.

These commands are provided by the package [pm-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pm-utils/), installed by default in Ubuntu 12.04LTS

**Source: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pm-action.8.html**

---

If you have problems with those commands, please see the source.  It states that

> On some hardware putting the video card in the suspend state and
>          recovering from it needs some special quirk handling. With the
>          --quirk-* options of the pm-suspend and pm-suspend-hybrid commands you
>          can select which quirks should be used.

A list of these quirks, and what they mean can be found [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pm-action.8.html#contenttoc3)

Comment: But `pm-hibernate` not working in all computers. Don't miss to test it. Close all files and programs, write in terminal `sudo pm-hibernate` and wait. If computer will hibernate successfully you can use it anytime you want. If not, forget it :)

Answer (score 2):

As an FYI, you can get the hibernation option back in the system menu by making the following changes (you should test the hibernate function from a terminal before doing this to ensure that it works properly):

```
 gksu gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

The previous command will open a new text file. Copy and paste the following into this new file:

```
[Enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Save and close the file.

Log out and log back in, and Hibernate should appear as an option in the system menu.