# How do I lock the screen from a terminal?

Tags: command-line, lock-screen

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. Is there any way to lock the screen or session from a terminal command or script?

Comment: Related: [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1792/327339)

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Simple:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

The following can also work, if the screensaver is set to lock when activate (see screensaver settings), since the command activates the screensaver:

```
gnome-screensaver-command -a
```

You can add an alias to the command by editing the file `.bashrc` (or `.bash_aliases`) in your home directory:

```
gedit $HOME/.bashrc
```

and adding the following line:

```
alias lock='gnome-screensaver-command -l'
```

Then from terminal:

```
source .profile
```

This will activate the alias.
From now on, the alias `lock` in a terminal will have the effect of locking the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I had to modify your changes. (i) no need to use sudo (ii) better .profile than .bashrc, since .bashrc gets called every time you create a new shell and (iii) alias works only when called from shell.

Comment: ok now its looking good , you like the idea ?

Comment: sure. I usually lock with a single keypress, though, makes it quicker when leaving the office for a coffee.

Comment: I think if we add more answer about creating a custom-shortcut key will improve , what do you say ?

Comment: Doesn't work, on my Linux mint mate, instead `xdg-screensaver lock` works.

Comment: @user218867 perfect for Pop_OS too.
Another command is `loginctl lock-session`.
To unlock the screen `loginctl unlock-session`.

Comment: `gnome-screensaver-command` doesn't appear to be installed but `xdg-screensaver lock` confirmed to work on Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: On Ubuntu 22.04, `gnome-screensaver-command` didn't come installed. I had to install it first with `sudo apt install gnome-screensaver`.

Answer (score 33):

In addition to what January said, this also works:

```
gnome-screensaver-command --lock
```

or

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

According to the `gnome-screensaver-command` man page...

```
-l, --lock                 Tells the running screensaver process to lock the screen immediately
-a, --activate             Turn the screensaver on (blank the screen)
```

For further clarification, here is another question/answer (also by January) which describes the differences between invoking the lock and activating your screensaver:

[Difference between gnome-screensaver-command -a and gnome-screensaver-command -l](https://askubuntu.com/questions/189741/difference-between-gnome-screensaver-command-a-and-gnome-screensaver-command-l/189780#189780)

Answer (score 25):

Starting in Ubuntu 14.04, Unity's lock screen no longer uses gnome-screensaver. The command `gnome-screensaver-command -l` will still work in most cases, but see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457204/how-can-i-lock-the-screen-using-the-new-lockscreen-from-the-command-line/492963) for exceptions.

If that command does not work (say, for instance, that gnome-screensaver is not installed), bringing up the proper Unity lock screen (not the greeter where you can switch users) can be done via this command in a terminal:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=org.gnome.ScreenSaver /org/gnome/ScreenSaver org.gnome.ScreenSaver.Lock
```

Answer (score 18):

Please install **vlock**. Then you can switch to a VT (text terminal, using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and run

```
vlock -a -s
```

This works whether you have X11 running or not.

Comment: looking nice . ok I'll try and let you know . thank you .

Comment: ok its looking good , but suits only for TTY .

Comment: Version `2.0.4` of `vlock` does not seem to have the `-s` switch anymore. Just running `vlock -a` works fine.

Comment: In Version 2.2.2, the `s` flag exists and is defined as `-s or --disable-sysrq: disable SysRq while consoles are locked to prevent killing vlock with SAK`. `SAK` is the secure attention key, which protects against trojan password capturing according to [kernel.org](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/SAK.txt). In a tty the `a` flag is enough to password protect.

Answer (score 16):

```
$!(sleep 10s ;  xset dpms force suspend) & xdg-screensaver lock
```

this starts the screen saver in locked mode and then puts your display in standby. sweet and simple, no sudo. command line or shell script works fine. i use this for a keyboard hotkey. Ubuntu Mate 15.10

Comment: Works on Kubuntu 16.04 too.

Comment: ty for xdg-screensaver lock, +1, however your answer didn't do the trick on ubuntu 16.10 gnome 3, i use: `xdg-screensaver lock && sleep 2s && sudo pm-suspend`. i have this aliased, and also with pm-suspend in my sudoers.d: `yourusername yourhostame = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend`

Comment: `ERROR: Unknown command 'lock'` in `Lubuntu 18.4. LTs`

Comment: Thank you - this works without installing gnome screen save

Answer (score 15):

In case that you need to lock the screen on a terminal in a non-GUI environment you could make use of [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)

While in `screen` press the following key combinations to lock the terminal.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

Comment: Thank you . now I'm in mobile . I'll try and let you know

Comment: For Tmux, `set-option -g lock-command vlock` (require vlock)

Answer (score 14):

In my case `xdg-screensaver lock` is works perfectly fine.
Also I save it by the setting or when I press <kbd>window</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> it will lock the screen immediately

Comment: holms@debian:~$ xdg-screensaver lock
ERROR: Unknown command 'lock'

Comment: This works on `Mint mate 20.1`, which is based on `Ubuntu 20.04`.

Comment: The accepted answer uses a command that I don't even have installed on Ubuntu 20.04. This one works without installing anything extra.

Answer (score 8):

For [LightDM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM) users, try `dm-tool switch-to-greeter`.

Comment: `dm-tool lock` seems better as that just locks the screen. "switch to greeter" ended my session when I tried it.

Comment: Using this in a cron job does not work?


Script : lock_script.sh
`#!/bin/sh
dm-tool switch-to-greeter`

Cron-job :  `42 9 * * * /home/user/lock-script.sh`

Comment: `dm-tool` is not very safe. Not on my system, anyway. Try going to a text TTY (Alt-Ctrl-F2) then back to your X TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F7 for me). It makes the lock screen disappear!

Answer (score 6):

A dirty hack of using the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for the locking the screen from a terminal:

1. Install xdotool from the software center or from the terminal as follows:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Type the following to lock the screen from the terminal:

   ```
   xdotool key Ctrl+alt+l
   ```

Refer to the manual page for xdotool for more.

Comment: This was definitely the best - because the other "screen-saver" based ones gave you a different "lock screen" which ONLY allows you to enter a password (no changer-user, logout, restart, etc). Also: May want to do stuff like:   DISPLAY=:0 sudo -u username xdotool key Ctrll+alt+l

Comment: nothing happens in dwm

Answer (score 4):

It depends on your display manager.
I have lightdm, I can do `dm-tool lock` to bring up a lock screen. It's not really secure, though, I found an easy way to bypass it.

Answer (score 1):

A similar situation to lock the screen in lubuntu

in **lubuntu** 17.10 (not ubuntu) this works `xset dpms force off`