# Difference between gnome-screensaver-command -a and gnome-screensaver-command -l

Tags: gnome, screensaver, gnome-screensaver

I was trying to figure out difference between

```
gnome-screensaver-command -a
```

and

```
gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

According to the `gnome-screensaver-command` man page...

```
-l, --lock                 Tells the running screensaver process to lock the screen immediately
-a, --activate             Turn the screensaver on (blank the screen)
```

For me in both the cases it generated the login screen.Can some one outline the difference in the two things??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that depends on the gnome-screensaver settings.

- If you set your gnome screensaver not to lock the screen, than the `-a` option will not lock the screen.
- If you set your gnome screensaver to lock the screen, then `-a` will lock it; this is the default setting in Ubuntu as far as I remember.
- Option `-l`, however, will always lock it.

Answer (score 3):

The help is accurate. It describes what they're *supposed* to do.

Your scenario suggests X is crashing and I would suggest filing a bug (via `ubuntu-bug gnome-screensaver`) and seeing where that takes you. It could be something as silly as the particular screensaver you have selected (try another).

Comment: I think that OP means that both commands lock the screen.