# Lock Terminal and Suspend from Terminal

Tags: command-line, suspend, lock, virtual-console, schedule

I am trying to lock and suspend from the terminal. I tried:

```
pmi action suspend | at now + 1 min
```

And then typed

```
exit
```

But both that and `vlock` kill the running command. Is there a way to lock the terminal and than get the computer to suspend using only Terminal commands?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/184728/how-do-i-lock-the-screen-from-a-terminal

Comment: This command only seems to work in a terminal running side the GUI. When I try and run it from a virtual terminal it dosn't work also it does not lock the virtual terminal itself.

Comment: Have you tried `pm-suspend` from the `pm-utils` package?

Comment: It is possible to use hibernate with full disk encryption. [hibernate from swap file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use `sudo -v;gnome-screensaver-command --lock;sleep 10;sudo pm-suspend`, with the `sleep` long enough for me to put the kbd and mouse away. Look at `man pm-action` for other commands (`pm-hibernate`,`pm-suspend-hybrid`), and be aware that hibernate doesn't work with encrypted swap.