# Is there any Desktop lock available

Tags: login

Is the any software available to just prevent the desktop from accessing (ie I want to lock the desktop, but want to downloads to continue)

Previously  I was using [clearlock](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/clearlock.html) on Windows

Comment: Can you clarify your question a little bit? Normally locking works exactly as you described.

Comment: No in normal locking, the download gets stopped. I just want any normal user to prevent access my desktop.

Comment: What download? Wget? D4a?

Comment: any download, I use DTA in Firefox

Comment: I suspect you did a `logout` rather lock screen, which could be why download was stopped.

Comment: There is no need for third-party software to lock your desktop on Windows: just use `Windows Key` + `L`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Ubuntu (with the default desktop settings), locking the desktop is done with `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `L`.

*Edit: I believe `Super` + `L` works too in recent versions of Ubuntu, which is the same as in Windows.*

No additional software is required.

This will not halt or pause any software. Downloads should continue as normal.

Answer (score 3):

Default `Lock` option must do the trick, but if you want a simple alternative, use `slock`

```
sudo apt-get install suckless-tools
```

You can lock by simply invoking slock at any terminal, or by binding it to a keyboard shortcut. To unlock, simply activate your display (if it got turned off), and blindly type in your password.

Note that there will not be any sort of indication of *echo back* of the password you type. You will see a plane blue screen. Type the password and hit enter to unlock.

Comment: I love all the suckless tools. I use them pretty frequently!

Answer (score 3):

To invoke a "lock" from the command line, you can accomplish this with `gnome-screensaver-command -l`, based on this Q/A: [How do I lock the screen from a terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184728/how-do-i-lock-the-screen-from-a-terminal/)

However, for a "clear" locking solution you can try xtrlock.

```
sudo apt-get install xtrlock
```

Then you can invoke it from a terminal:

```
xtrlock
```

This will allow you to continue to view the desktop, while remaining locked.  To unlock it, just type your password.

**Note**: I was confused by this at first, because it never presents you with a dialog or prompt to enter your password.  You just start typing it, and it unlocks when you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.