# Password protection for command-line suspension

Tags: 14.04, command-line, password, suspend

I found out how to suspend via command line, namely by `sudo pm-suspend`. What I miss there is that when the machine wakes back up, the **sessions** (all of them running in different tty's) are not protected by password. I checked the man page for `pm` and this aspect is nowehere to be found there. Thus two questions:

1) How to make it work simply?

2) I could make an alias for pm-suspend, but then, what should I put there as instructions? Is there any way to log out of a shell session without killing it? Which is an interesting question on its own.

EDIT:

The question is about how to lock a shell session running outside any X environment (Gnome, etc).

EDIT:

To find out what I mean press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F1` and follow from there. But make sure you know how to go back before you jump there :-)

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? We might have to distinguish between *upstart* and *systemd*.

Comment: 14.04 64-bit. I know neither of them yet.

Comment: Do you say that you don't have a GUI on your notebook and get asked for a password when suspending by closing the lid?

Comment: I have a GUI, but it's about tty 1 to 6. And it's about NOT being asked when back awake.

Comment: AFAIK tty simply don't have the concept of "session", thats why I assumed a GUI.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I lock the screen from a terminal?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184728/how-do-i-lock-the-screen-from-a-terminal) (look at the answer about `vlock`)

Comment: That's not a duplicate. This one's not about Gnomes etc. As for the former, press Alt+Ctrl+F1 and see.

Comment: @guntbert No, this for suspending (not locking) from a TTY (not from a desktop environment). @ Tomasz how about `sudo pm-suspend && exit`?

Comment: @kos Are you serious?

Comment: @gunbert The `vlock` answer is relevant though. But only partially. And now I need to find out how to vlock all tty's running a session.

Comment: I think I missed the fact that you want to lock multiple sessions. Then no, I wasn't serious. It seems like `vlock` would work well for that.

Comment: I just removed my last comment. `vlock -a && pm-suspend` doesn't work. And it blocks in a way it asks for root's password and doesn't accept mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I can answer my question myself. Still, give more answers if you have them.

`sudo pm-suspend && vlock -a` does the trick. But it requires the vlock being installed. And don't make it the other way round, ie. `sudo vlock -a && pm-suspend`, as it will ask for root's password on wake up, and there is no such thing in Ubuntu, as far as I know.