# Super+L doesn't lock screen if auto-login is on

Tags: lock-screen, auto-login

I have activated auto login in Settings -> Users -> Automatic Login

Now <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> does nothing. It should lock the screen.

How can I restore <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> behaviour?

Ubuntu 20.10, GNOME 3.38, Linux 5.8

Comment: You can disable auto login ...

Comment: @SorenA I want auto login + screen lock.

Comment: see if you can do it manually from terminal https://askubuntu.com/questions/184728/how-do-i-lock-the-screen-from-a-terminal ..... then set a manul keyboard shortcut with super-L or other key if that does not work.