# No permission to suspend/hibernate after upgrading to 12.10

Tags: suspend, 12.10, hibernate

After upgrading to Ubuntu 12.10, when I click on suspend/hibernate in the menu, nothing happens. When I run pm-hibernate or pm-suspend in the terminal, I was told that i need to be root to use them. Of course, sudo pm-hibernate and sudo pm-suspend can work. How do I get the hibernate/suspend buttons in my menu to work again?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line)

Comment: Looks like ben is first interested in getting the menu item to work.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a workaround. First you'll need to create a script that is on your PATH. I'd recommend putting something like this in your `~/.bashrc` file if you don't have it already:

```
PATH=/home/<username>/bin:$PATH
```

Then create a script `/home/<username>/bin/pm-suspend` which contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo pm-suspend
```

Finally edit the sudoers file to not ask for a password for the `pm-suspend` command:

```
sudo visudo
```

Add the following line as the last rule in the file:

```
<username> ALL=NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

If you now launch a new terminal window/tab you should now be able to run pm-suspend without sudo and suspend from your desktop. It's a bit or a bodge but seems to work for now.