# Getting "critical temp reached" shutdowns randomly, without fans or very high CPU temps

Tags: overheating

With hardly any CPU intensity (ex. just Chrome and Atom open) my HP Spectre x360  will randomly shutdown. After checking the system logs, thermald sends a priority 6 critical temp, which shuts everything down.

Fans are not going strong and there doesn't appear to be any throttling. In fact, the previous logs, less than 10 mins before indicate that all CPU cores meet "Package Temperature/Speed Normal."

Two things I think it could be, either the computer is actually overheating without throttling, hard fans, etc. Or the Kernel is misreading CPU temps momentarily, which initiates an immediate shutdown.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
Linux spectre-x360 4.13.0-39-generic #44-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 5 14:25:01 `UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What temperatures are shown by `sensors` (from the package `lm-sensors`)?

Comment: @forest I don't know what temp they were during shutdown. But right now, doing the same tasks, they hover around 45-55C.

Comment: What log file was the error in and what is a unique part of the message that I can use to grep for it?  I had an unexpected shutdown out of the blue the other day and I'd like to see if was similar to your issue.

Comment: @rkeating `sudo grep -Hrn 'critical temp' /var/log`  - See if it showns up in a "syslog" as a thermald  message.

Comment: It didn't come up with anything. Sorry I can't be of any help.

Comment: From this answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature/854029#854029 Try this command to see all your temperature zones. Perhaps one sensor is not working properly: `paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t`

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix thanks! The sensors all seem nominal though.

Comment: @BraedenSmith Do you have TLP and Powerclamp installed? See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating Also you might want to try kernel `4.15.0-29`