# Document viewer (evince) couldn't open pdf when system upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: upgrade, 18.04, pdf, evince

I just upgraded the system from 16.04 LTS to 18.04 LTS. Everything works fine until I tried to open pdf. It seems the document viewer could not open pdf files that look normal previously. However, those pdf files are OK as I can view them in chrome in 18.04. Any idea on how to fix the document viewer?

Here is the error message:

> "Failed to load backend for 'applicaton/pdf': libpoppler-glib.so.8:
>   failed to map segment from shared object

Here is a snapshot of the screen:
[image]

Another one:
[image]

Following the suggestions of N0rbert, some additional information is attached as follows.

First, `apt-cache policy libpoppler-glib8`:

```
$ apt-cache policy libpoppler-glib8
libpoppler-glib8:
  Installed: 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.1
  Candidate: 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.1
  Version table:
 *** 0.62.0-2ubuntu2.1 500
        500 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.62.0-2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

The output of `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-glib.so.8 | grep not` is empty.

---

Note:

- For those who have similar issue, I found both Foxit Reader and
  qpdfview work fine on my computer and I finally decide to use Foxit
  reader as a workaround as its UI is more friendly in my opinion.
- Feel free to comment if additional information is required. I'll
  respond as soon as possible.

Comment: have you tried installing/reinstalling libpoppler?

Comment: @JoshuaBesneatte, Yeah. I tried reinstall libpoppler and libpoppler-glib8. Neither works. I also tried remove evince and reinstall it. Same thing :(

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libpoppler-glib8` and `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpoppler-glib.so.8  | grep not` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert, I appended those information to the question.  I would be happy to provide any other information that might be helpful.

Comment: Did you tried to open other pdf-files from other locations? For example `evince /usr/share/doc/shared-mime-info/shared-mime-info-spec.pdf`.

Comment: @N0rbert, did you mean files in different directories? Yes, I tried and got the same error. It seems the document viewer could not open any pdf file on my disk now. I also added the screenshot for the `shared-mime-info-spec.pdf` in the question.

Comment: This might be of some help: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/363355

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, I have read the post just now. And I didn't found any line containing `libpoppler` in the output of `ldd $(which evince)` on my computer. Does this look like the cause of the error?

Comment: What's odd is the `failed to map segment from shared object` error isn't presenting a reason, usually does. Try `sudo apt purge libevview3-3 libevdocument3-4`  & then `sudo apt clean  &&  sudo apt install evince`

Comment: @doug, I tried the exact command in your comment and the error still exists :(

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, that link is really helpful. When I browsed that page again, I checked my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and found it is pointing to a single dir. Somehow, there is another copy of `libpoppler-cpp.so` and `libpoppler-glib.so.8`. I moved `libpopper*` to another directory and the evince worked. It seems that dynamic linker searches `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` before `/lib` and `/usr/lib`. I think the bounty belongs to you if you have time to write an answer. Another thing is that I forget which software installed that copy. Removing that copy might affect it.

Comment: @mt1022 Thank you. There are still 5 days left on your bounty and I'm in the middle of general design for this project: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063363/laptop-cpugpu-overheating-after-update-to-18-04-lts/1065125#1065125. I will post an answer over the next couple of days if that is acceptable?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix, of course. Do it at your own pace.

Comment: @mt1022 I hope the answer is worded properly. Let me know if revisions are in order. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Library path incorrect

Nine years ago on this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/363355) it was discovered:

> installed a version without using the packaging system and it's taking
>   over the ubuntu build and breaking your installation
>
> " libpoppler-glib.so.4 => /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-glib.so.4
>   (0xb78b0000)"
>
> clean that and it should be working correctly

The solution was to remove:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/local/lib/libpoppler-glib.so.4
```

---

Nine years later and you have a similar problem.  Checking `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is pointing to a single dir rather than the full path list. There is an incorrect version of `libpoppler-cpp.so` and `libpoppler-glib.so.8` there.

Moving `libpopper*` to another directory allowed `evince` to work with the proper dynamic linker searches in `/lib` and `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reinstalling evince by performing:

```
sudo apt purge evince
sudo apt install evince
```

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort. I tried the commands but the evince is not fixed. Same error remains.