# Why Ubuntu does not release his OS for Intel Processor (ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64) i have problem with installing Ubuntu on intel processo?

Tags: 18.04, intel, acer, 20.04, amd-processor

Since the downloaded file from Ubuntu website always consist of AMD64 such as **ubuntu-20.04-desktop-amd64**. I think my Acer Predator Helio 300 which has Intel i7 7th gen processor does not fit well. Because i try to install 3 to 4 times of Ubuntu 18.04 with Proper installation and proper installation of NVIDIA 1060 Graphics card.But there is always problem of Overheating and unexpected shut down of the laptop.

My Question is there is another OS Build for Intel processors laptop?

My mainly work of building ML and Neural Net model. And Sometime for fun i am building Android and ISO Apps. Could you please suggest what is the problem with my laptop with Ubuntu and could i need to switch some other distro then what is the best distro for my work.

**"I will be grateful for any help you can provide with this situation."**

Comment: I think your problem is something else ...

Comment: Are you running 18.04 or 20.04? Do you have `lm-sensors` installed? What are your CPU temps? Have you installed Nvidia drivers? If so, what version?

Answer (score 1):

amd64 it's an architecture, not the processor model. You choose the right variant. Root of your problem is not here.

Comment: Could you have any other idea brother for my problem ?

Comment: For that you need to give much more detail like syslog output, etc.. Best is you ask a new question. Check out also some other [Questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063363/laptop-cpugpu-overheating-after-update-to-18-04-lts) before doing so.