# Is there a way to set temperature thresholds in Ubuntu?

Tags: overheating, temperature

I want my fans to turn on before my laptop gets too hot for my lap, I'm not sure how I would do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop cpu from overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put your laptop on your lap. Your clothing can block the intact vents. You should put your laptop on a cooling pad:

[image: cooling pad.png]

The cooling pad in turn you can put on your lap or your couch, coffee table, bed, etc.

The fans on laptops are controlled by the manufacturer and kick in at given temperatures. To prevent your laptop from turning off when it gets too hot you can use **Intel Powerclamp**. Additionally you should be using `thermald` and `tlp`.

See: [Stop cpu from overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872)