# Nvidia gpu getting hot in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, graphics, overheating, temperature

I'm new to the Ubuntu world, and even though I love the vibe, I cannot use it professionally (I'm web Dev). I have set up a dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Turns out that when nothing is open,  the sensors on the GPU show up to 45-48°C. When Chrome is open, the temperature goes above 60°C. If I want to open VS Code, it heats up to over 80°C when I put it on a cooling pad. My laptop is a Lenovo Ideapad 530S, i7 1.80 GHz, 16 GB RAM, NVIDIA GeForce MX150.On Windows with 3 VS Code Windows, over 20 tabs open in chrome, slack and discord app opened, the GPU temp is barely 41°C.
Does anybody have similar problems?

Terminal output from `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
Subsystem: Lenovo UHD Graphics 620
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915


01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GP108M [GeForce MX150]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Comment: Is proprietary driver installed?

Comment: I have 470.82.00 nvidia driver installed, is that what You asking about?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: There are a number of things you can do to [Prevent CPU from Overheating](https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating/875872#875872). These may apply to GPU at the same time. On my dual fan laptop the GPU is always a few degrees hotter than the other sensors though.

Comment: @Pilot6 i added output that You have asked for

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix its is hotter, but if it reaches 80°C with 2 chrome window open and 2 vs code workspaces, then I know something isn't right, i have checked all trick with different software and changing diver's settings, and it's not helping. I know i am not the only one with the issue, I am looking for somebody that has the same experience and solved this problem

Comment: @KamilSzewczyk You could try turning off hardware acceleration in Chrome. Also update your question with details of your fan. EG is it on and loud when the system is hot?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix problem is not in chrome - its getting hot just for running the system, i can touch it and its quite warm. You can hear the fan, its working on maximum torque, bot does not help. Its not fan problem as a hardware, cause on Win10 everything is perfectly cool, for example, when Im typing this, I have GPU on 41°C, with over 20 card open in 2 chrome windows, and 2 vs code editors. Cannot hear fans