# Suspend command in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, suspend, dbus

In Ubuntu 14.04 I used to use the following command to suspend the computer as a user without root privileges:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest="org.freedesktop.UPower" \
/org/freedesktop/UPower org.freedesktop.UPower.Suspend
```

Unfortunately in Ubuntu 16.04 this doesn't work anymore and I get an error message:

> Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such method 'Suspend'

Apparently there has been some changes so **what would be the correct command now?**

Answer (score 40, accepted):

As per [Debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/UserShutdown), with systemd this is the new command:

```
systemctl suspend
```

**NOTE**: This command still [requires](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Power_management) root privileges if there is **another user's session open**. It also doesn't work in **Cron**. In both cases you you will need to create extra [settings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/289341/50336).

Comment: For information, `-i` means `ignore-inhibitors` (See systemctl manpage: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/systemctl.1.html) which might not be what you want.

Comment: @CJlano, thanks for bringing it up because I was actually wondering whether to include this flag in my answer. The reason I did was that during my (brief) test the suspend seems to be not performed if some other user is logged in and the flag is not used. I will have another closer look into it. Meanwhile, if you have some more information on how to create command line equivalent of the suspend performed in GUI, please come up with a new answer or post it as a comment and I will include your info in mine (and give you credit :-)).

Comment: Is there a way to make it also lock the screen? (Using Ubuntu MATE.)

Comment: This command works without `sudo` for Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 2):

`Suspend` method is still available on D-Bus, if needed:

```
dbus-send \
  --system \
  --print-reply \
  --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 \
  /org/freedesktop/login1 \
  org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend \
  boolean:true
```

`boolean:true` is the `user_interaction` parameter:

> The user_interaction boolean parameters can be used to control whether PolicyKit should interactively ask the user for authentication credentials if it needs to.

[Source](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/)

Comment: Does it means it might ask password before entering suspend?

Comment: I can't say for sure, but I don't think it will. The `user_interaction` parameter is mandatory, which is why I explained it, but it doesn't necessarily mean that `Suspend` is affected by it.