# Start application at resume

Tags: startup, suspend, hibernate

How do I automatically start an application on resume after suspend or hibernate?

The reason I want to do this is because I've created a script to set xinput value on startup application, but after suspend or hibernate the value in xinput back to default.

Answer (score 1):

Place the custom shell script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`. Here's an example script which restarts `autokey-gtk`:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
        ;;
    thaw|resume)
        pkill autokey-gtk
        nohup autokey-gtk 2>&1 > /dev/null &
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac
```

The script name should start with 99, or something like that. For example: `99_my_resume.bash`.

And don't forget to make it executable:

```
chmod +x 99_my_resume.bash
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I can't suspend or hibernate with 99*.bash file in sleep.d

Comment: Did You run it as `/etc/pm/sleep.d/99_my_resume.bash suspend` to suspend? Also You didn't ask to suspend, You asked to run a program on resume. So did You try it?

Comment: No, that 99 file is my script, which I expect to run *after* resuming from suspend. My machine is able to suspend before I put that file in sleep.d, but if the 99 file in sleep.d, I cant suspend, I dont know if it works or not after suspend because I cant suspend at all with the file in sleep.d

Comment: You did `chmod`, right? I would try what the command line complains when it fails to suspend, if I were You. Here's [a link](http://askubuntu.com/a/1795/21679) to suspend from command line.

Comment: You see I've used the way for some time myself. A year ago or something like that. It should be working.

Comment: Yes i've made it executable, looks like my problem cant be solved and I have to run my script manually when resuming from suspend, not a big deal though, just need a double click and click run. anyway, thanks for answering.