# Hibernation on multi-user system

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Xubuntu 13.10 and am having problems with hibernation when multiple users are logged in.

I have already re-enabled hibernation as detailed in this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/1232814 .

My issue is if there are more than one active sessions. My situation is I am the only users with admin rights (I belong to sudo) on the family computer. If one of the kids suspends their session instead of logging out then I have difficulty hibernating.

My difficulty is, I choose "Hibernate" from the action menu, the screen is locked but never hibernates. When I unlock the screen I'm prompted to supply my password to hibernate.

I, and all others users, am able to suspend when others are logged in. I am able to hibernate as expected it no one else in logged in. I am able to hibernate if others are logged in by using "sudo pm-hibernate".

Previous releases allowed me to hibernate the computer when others were logged in.

To be clear when I say "logged in" the other accounts are not being remotely used, I mean the user didn't terminate his session.

I can think of no solution to this after stumbling around in policykit settings.

Comment: Exactly the same problem here. Except I don't even have any other active session (but maybe some running services that send me to the same situation...) Very annoying though.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger If this is a bug, there's nothing that anyone on this site can do, ultimately you will have to wait until there is a fix released for this issue, I'm not sure why you wasted 50 rep on what is essentially a bug report...

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger - I agree with Thomas.  This is best tracked on Launchpad.  I've returned your bounty to you.

Comment: Hard to tell werther it is a bug or not. I'll report to Launchpad then. But it's hard to believe we're only two experiencing the issue. Thanks for support

Comment: Before any fixing, this post helped me (if some other people face the same problem). http://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line/131022#131022 So I'll hibernate from command line instead of menu from now on. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @ThomasW. I forgot to *actually* read the question posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered this is controlled by:
`/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.login1.policy` action item `org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions`

Instead of changing the setting here and potentially losing it during an update I created:
`/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate-multi-sessions.pkla`
With the contents:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by if mutliple seesions are active]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

Now I can hibernate the computer no matter how many sessions are active.