# Keep keyboard from waking laptop?

Tags: 13.10, keyboard, laptop, suspend

I have an Ideapad Y400 running Ubuntu 13.10.  I have been having a problem where, while I am carrying the laptop, the screen will push one of the keys and wake the laptop up.  Is there any way to:

- Disable the keyboard when the laptop goes to sleep,
- Keep the keyboard from waking the laptop, or
- Make the laptop go to back to sleep if it is woken while closed?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a script (cron job that runs it every minute, or plain loop in the background) that checks the lid state (/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID/state on my Lenovo P50 with 16.04) and if it find it closed, issues a [suspend command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line#1795).

Another way is to disable resume. Normally there is only one key for resume (the Fn key), and there could be a way to disable it in the BIOS (you would still be able to resume with the touchpad).

The low tech way is some thin card put over the keys before closing the lid :)