# How to restore the session in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, suspend, hibernate

I am new to Ubuntu and I am using Ubuntu 12.04(64 bits) on hp pavilion dv5 dual boot with windows 7. I have tried every thing I could to enable hibernation in Ubuntu posted on the forum but nothing seems to work. I even tried to use suspend but I couldn't restore as my system got hanged up on a black screen showing nothing, forcing me to hard boot the system again.

Now I am starting a project that has a necessity of working on Ubuntu, so I need to have something that could allow me to restore my session after I shut down just like hibernate.

So is there any third party tool available that could be used to save the session and whenever I switch my laptop on I could resume all the application as I left. Or any other suggestion to help me in this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In Xubuntu you can go to settings manager -> Session and Startup, there is a checkbox you can click to save session on logout if you log off and shutdown, it will still have the session saved when you turn it back on. (Answer assumes ubuntu desktop use)

Many computers do not support Linux hibernation and so it is not enabled by default in Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10.

Comment: Hi TurtleMoviesCo,

Thank you for the reply. But I couldn't see an session or Startup in my settings manager and secondly I am using command line. I have inserted various commands in the files and saved them to enable hibernate but no success. :/

Comment: Well maybe this will help you.http://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line @Vinod Madan