# How to suspend from the command line in gnome 3.14

Tags: command-line, gnome, suspend

I'm aware of this post: [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line)

however, the recommended method using dbus doesn't work with Gnome Shell 3.14.0.

What is the now recommended approach for suspending from the command line?

(I use Ubuntu 14.10 beta and the gnome-team ppa)

Comment: See this answer in that question: http://askubuntu.com/a/508164/158442

Comment: As OP indicates this does not work for him. I personally use `sudo pm-suspend`.

Comment: Software in a team PPA is not part of a release and is not supported as such.

Comment: @StephenMichaelKellat ["Questions that you may ask: ....Running third-party applications on Ubuntu."](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) This doesn't guarantee every possible question about such software is considered on-topic, but if you think this question is beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu, I recommend explaining specifically why, in accordance with existing site policies. (In particular, this might be considered to go against our policy of generally prohibiting questions about problems with alpha and beta versions of Ubuntu, though there's some flexibility this close to the release date.)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks for the pointer @muru.

The correct command is:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply \
  --dest="org.freedesktop.login1" \
  /org/freedesktop/login1 \
  org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend boolean:true
```

Comment: Obv, replace `Suspend` with `Hibernate` to hibernate.