# How to create keyboard shortcut which initiates suspend

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, suspend, function-keys

When I was running the Unity shell I was able to do <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> and get my machine to suspend, however now that I am running Gnome Shell, when I do this keyboard shortcut, absolutely nothing happens, so I was wondering if there was anyway to get it so that when doing that keyboard shortcut, my machine does actually suspend?

I have tried looking in my System Settings and found nothing obvious, I have also looked in Gnome Tweak Tool, but still nothing obvious. When I had Unity it was just the case though, and even when I had Windows 7 before that it was the case that that keyboard combination did that, I have never needed to configure anything specially, nor have I to get this working.

---

**OS Information:**

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
Release:    15.04
Codename:   vivid
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tested the command mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/536706/72216) on Gnome 15.04, and it did the job well. The next thing to do is then to make it available under a shortcut key.

The easiest way would be to create a small script of it:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

dbus-send --system --print-reply \
  --dest="org.freedesktop.login1" \
  /org/freedesktop/login1 \
  org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend boolean:true
```

save it as `initiate_suspend.sh`, and make it available under a shortcut key. To do that works the same in `Gnome` as it works in `Unity`: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

```
/bin/bash /path/to/initiate_suspend.sh
```

to a shortcut key combination of your choice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26269/discussion-on-answer-by-jacob-vlijm-how-to-create-keyboard-shortcut-which-initia).

Comment: @Mitch sorry (again) I'll remember for next time.

Comment: No worries.. -:)

Comment: Seems to work in Xfce, too, though it does not lock desktop. (Xfce has a specific command `xfce4-session-logout --suspend` which does, if set)

Answer (score 4):

To suspend Ubuntu 18.10 I use the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to launch a command and type `sus` to highlight the Suspend command, then hit <kbd>Return</kbd>.

[image: screenshot]

Not quick as elegant as <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>l</kbd> to lock screen, but it works without adding any configuration and no need for a mouse.

Answer (score 4):

I know this post is old. But in new Gnome versions, it's very easy.

Simply go to **settings > keyboard > keyboard shortcuts** and add a **custom shortcut** with this command `systemctl suspend`.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this

```
gksudo pm-suspend
```

in Settings>>Keyboard>>Shortcut and map it to any key combination you want.

Answer (score 0):

### Using `pm-utils` with PolicyKit

With this way, you have to enter a password before suspend.

1. First install `pm-utils`, we need `pm-suspend`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install pm-utils
   ```
2. After that, create a new script file and add the code below

   ```sh
   #!/bin/sh
   pkexec "pm-suspend" "$@"
   ```
3. Open Keyboard via <kbd>Activities</kbd> menu and navigate to <kbd>Custom Shortcuts</kbd> and add a new shortcut.

   [image: screenshot]

   [image: screenshot]
4. Now add a new file in `/usr/share/polkit-1/actions/`

   ```
    sudo nano cat /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/pm-suspend.policy
   ```

   And add the lines below

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
    "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">

   <policyconfig>

     <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.run-pm-suspend">
       <description>Run FlashTool</description>
       <message>Authentication is required to run pm-suspend</message>
       <defaults>
         <allow_any>no</allow_any>
         <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
         <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
       </defaults>
       <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/sbin/pm-suspend</annotate>
       <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
     </action>

   </policyconfig>
   ```

That's all **;)**

Answer (score 0):

Here a exaple how to create keyboard shortcut to suspend the system by pressing `<Super> + s` keys:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys suspend "['<Super>s']"
```

or create a custom keybinding:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys custom-keybindings "['/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/']"
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ name 'suspend'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ command 'systemctl suspend'
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.custom-keybinding:/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom0/ binding '<Super>p'
```

Comment: Be a little careful with using 'Copy and Paste' answers for questions in AU.