# screen is not locked after suspend/lid closed

Tags: suspend, lock-screen

My screen doesn't get locked after I close my laptop lid. The laptop suspends but the screen is not locked.

I checked multiple settings:

```
gnome-control-center > brightness & lock > lock on and require password when waking from suspend enabled
dconf-editor > org/gnome/desktop/lockdown/disable-lock-screen disabled
dconf-editor > org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/lock-enabled enabled
dconf-editor > org/gnome/desktop/screensaver/ubuntu-lock-on-suspend enabled
```

But can't get to lock my screen after suspend. What else can I try?

Answer (score 3):

Not a solution, but you may use this script as a workaround:

```
#!/bin/bash
qdbus com.canonical.Unity /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.Lock &&
qdbus com.canonical.Unity  /com/canonical/Unity/Session com.canonical.Unity.Session.Suspend
```

This works with stock Ubuntu with Unity desktop. The approach is specific to Unity, although there are `dbus` calls to suspend regardless of the desktop environment. For 16.04 , one could use `systemctl suspend` command. See the relevant post: https://askubuntu.com/a/1795/295286

#### Alternative (older answer, edited)

One of the other tools for suspending, that works regardless of the Ubuntu version is `pm-suspend`. Problem is that it requires root privilege. To work around that, add pm-suspend to `/etc/sudoers` file to be executed without password ( more info [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/159007/295286) ).

In particular, in my `/etc/sudoers` I have the following:

```
# Allow using pm-suspend for my user without password
serg ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/pm-suspend
```

Thus, you can use:

```
sh -c 'gnome-screensaver-command -l && sudo pm-suspend'
```

The `sudo pm-suspend` won't prompt you for password then.

Comment: Hi, it didn't work for me. Using Ubuntu 14.04. It suspends, but that's it. No locking.

Comment: @AkeshwarJha  Interesting. Check if you have `gnome-screensaver-command`. It's one of the standard ones. Are you using the stock Ubuntu with Unity desktop ?

Comment: yes. I'm using the stock Ubuntu with Unity desktop. I ran `gnome-screensaver-command -l` independently and it did lock my screen. i ran 'sudo pm-suspend' independently, and it suspended my system without lock. But combining these two only suspends my computer, doesn't lock it.

Comment: @AkeshwarJha OK, so I figured out that when one tries to run `gnome-screensaver-comand -l` as root, it tries to lock for `root`'s GUI session, which isn't running. I've edited my answer accordingly and added alternative solution with `qdbus`. That one works with Unity and doesn't require no `sudo` password.

Comment: [Here's an alternative one-liner](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474754/327339) that both locks the screen and suspends the computer in one command. This keeps me from having to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file. Good answer, by the way. Upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing similar issue [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/832461/615415) answer solved my issue. Install Unity Tweak Tool and in System > Security all the options should be unticked. The Desktop Lock was ticked in my case uncheck this.

[image: uncheck]

If the above mentioned option is ticked then in System Settings > Brightness and Lock the lock option is disabled which causes all the problem.

[image: lock option]

Answer (score 0):

### How to lock the screen and put the computer to sleep in a 1-liner from the command line (could be assigned to an Ubuntu shortcut key)

*Tested on Ubuntu 22.04.*

This isn't an answer directly to the question, but it may help some people:

You can lock the screen and put the computer to sleep in a single command like this:

```bash
# lock the screen and put the computer to sleep
sudo true && gnome-screensaver-command -l && sudo pm-suspend
```

You can assign the above command to a shortcut key if you want to quickly put your computer to sleep.

After putting your computer to sleep with the command above, you can then wake up your computer and verify it went to sleep like this:

```bash
journalctl -n 1000 -e | grep "PM: suspend"
```

You'll see some suspend entries. Here's an example run and output for me. Check the timestamps to ensure this is for the suspend you just did:

```bash
$ journalctl -n 1000 -e | grep "PM: suspend"
Jun 25 23:07:02 gabriel-my-computer-name kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Jun 25 23:07:17 gabriel-my-computer-name kernel: PM: suspend exit
```

**Explanation of the first command above, and how it works:**

1. `sudo true` prompts your user for a password to run sudo. Once you type in your `sudo` password, it gets temporarily cached. `true` is a dummy command to always pass. So, on to the next command.
2. `gnome-screensaver-command -l` runs as *non*-sudo, locking the screen for your user's session.
3. Now that the screen is locked, `sudo pm-suspend` runs to suspend the system. It uses your cached `sudo` password that you entered and which was cached a moment ago when you ran `sudo true`.

The trick is to use `sudo true` first, to cached your password, since obviously once the screen is locked, you cannot type the password, and `gnome-screensaver-command -l` *must* run as *non* sudo!

### What *not* to do

Don't do this! It will freeze your computer and require a hard reboot where you have to hold down your power button:

```bash
# bad: this locks up your computer; freezes laptop!; requires hard reboot
sudo pm-suspend && gnome-screensaver-command -l
```

### References

1. Where I first learned about `sudo pm-suspend`, and `journalctl`, in general: https://learnubuntumate.weebly.com/draining-battery.html

### See also

1. My shorter answer which references this one: [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1485370/327339)