# When using && and sudo on the first command, is the second command run as sudo too?

Tags: bash, sudo

If I run a command.

```
sudo some-command && some-other-command
```

Is the second command being run with `sudo` previlege also?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

TL;DR: **NO**

---

The first command is

```
sudo some-command
```

The second command is

```
some-other-command
```

The command `sudo` takes the following command and executes it with elevated privileges. The `&&`, however, doesn't belong to a command and is interpreted by the shell, before executing the first command. It tells bash to first execute the first command, and on success the second one.

So the `sudo` doesn't know about the `&& some-other command`. When the elevated process terminates, bash takes its return value, and then executes the other command, which again doesn't know of the first one.

This can be demonstrated easily:

```
$ sudo whoami && whoami
root
username
```

To reach what you want, you can start an elevated bash, and let it execute both commands:

```
$ sudo bash -c 'whoami && whoami'
root
root
```

So now, both commands are executed as root, as the whole process described above is executed in an elevated process, i.e. the bash session started with this command, which immediately exits after finishing. Still, the both `whoami`s don't know of each others existence.

This does not suit any purpose but for this demonstration, the easier way is to simply do

```
sudo some-command && sudo some-other-command
```

Comment: Tweeted out https://twitter.com/StackExchange/status/609076664795033600

Comment: This demonstration is really cool! Got to think of it when trying to teach sudo to others next time!

Comment: I need some help: what I need is `cmd1 && sudo cmd2`, except `cmd1` locks the screen, meaning that when `cmd2` tries to run with `sudo`, and `sudo` requests your password, there's no way to see the request nor type it in. How to solve this I wonder?

Comment: I got it!: here's my answer: [How to lock the screen and put the computer to sleep in a 1-liner from the command line](https://askubuntu.com/a/1474754/327339). `sudo true &&` is the secret.

Answer (score 21):

No. Some examples that do this are:

```
sudo some-command && sudo some-other-command 
sudo sh -c "some-command && some-other-command"
```

or if you want nest commands you can even do:

```
sudo bash <<"EOF"
some-command
some-other-command
sudo bash <<"EOF2"
    some-command2
    some-other-command2
EOF2
EOF
```

- The 2nd uses another shell.
- Mind that when you use ' or " in the 2nd version you need to escape those in the commands or parameters of that command (ie. \' or \") so that can get complex very quickly.

Comment: Third method does not work: `$ sudo -s -- whoami && whoami` gives `root` `username`

Comment: @BartekChom sorry I missed the quotes on that one

Comment: `sudo -s -- "whoami && whoami"` seems to give command not found, more or less the same as command `"whoami && whoami"`. How to use this construction with &&? I see that  `sudo -s cd ..` gives no error as opposed to `sudo cd ..`.

Comment: I've learnt something new today: `sudo bash <<"EOF"`!  Thanks!  :-)

Answer (score 5):

No, either you must write sudo twice, or do something like

```
sudo bash -c 'foo && bar'
```

Answer (score 3):

`&&` means that the right sided (second) command will only run only if the lest sided (first) command is successful i.e. exit code `$?` is `0`.

The two commands are different from each other and will run in their own environments so the second command will not run having `sudo` privilege.

This will make you clear:

```
$ sudo whoami && whoami 
root
foobar
```

Answer (score 2):

NO, and the following was once very commonly macro'd.

```
sudo reboot && exit
```

Just about everybody should have done this at least *once*

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Thus it is a great "mickey mouse" interview question.

This is so easily tested that the question may be suspected to a stat padding exercise.

Answer (score 0):

On the command line, when you see

```
$ command one && command two
```

the typical intent is to execute the command that follows the && only if the first command is successful.

#### Is the other command runs as sudo also?

absolutely no, this is just as writing two consecutive  commands, this && gives no added privilege to a command. **It's just a seperator**.

To prove that let us take an example.

```
touch fileA fileB
```

I created two files fileA and fileB. Now I'll run the command

```
sudo chown test:test fileA && chown test:test fileB
```

I'm changing user and group owner of these files to user and group name test. Now the first command should run while what about the other?

The output is:

```
chown: changing ownership of `fileB': Operation not permitted
```

So the command didn't run since it needs `sudo` and though we can conclude that && is not a replacement of the second `sudo`