# This a problem with /etc/sudoers.d file?

Tags: apt, dpkg, sudo, root, policykit

After executing this line, the return worried me.

```
~$ sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

```
    E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
    E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

```
    ~$ dpkg --verify
```

```
dpkg: warning: linux-image-5.8.0-31-generic: unable to open /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-31-generic for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-31-generic
dpkg: warning: geoclue-2.0: unable to open /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/geoclue-2.0.pkla for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/geoclue-2.0.pkla
dpkg: warning: systemd: unable to open /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/systemd-networkd.pkla for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/systemd-networkd.pkla
dpkg: warning: network-manager: unable to open /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.pkla
dpkg: warning: linux-modules-5.8.0-25-generic: unable to open /boot/System.map-5.8.0-25-generic for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /boot/System.map-5.8.0-25-generic
dpkg: warning: sudo: unable to open /etc/sudoers for hash: Permission denied
??5?????? c /etc/sudoers
dpkg: warning: sudo: unable to open /etc/sudoers.d/README for hash: Permission denied
??5?????? c /etc/sudoers.d/README
dpkg: warning: linux-modules-5.8.0-31-generic: unable to open /boot/System.map-5.8.0-31-generic for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /boot/System.map-5.8.0-31-generic
dpkg: warning: packagekit: unable to open /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.pkla for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/org.freedesktop.packagekit.pkla
dpkg: warning: cups-filters: unable to open /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-brf for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-brf
dpkg: warning: policykit-desktop-privileges: unable to open /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
dpkg: warning: fwupd: unable to open /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/fwupd.pkla for hash: Permission denied
??5??????   /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/fwupd.pkla
```

I'm trying to figure it out by myself, but I'm stuck with this.

Comment: See [When using && and sudo on the first command, is the second command run as sudo too?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634620/when-using-and-sudo-on-the-first-command-is-the-second-command-run-as-sudo-t)

Comment: Problem solved.