# Hibernate/suspend on critical battery level - where should I set it from MATE GUI?

Tags: 16.04, suspend, battery, hibernate, mate

I have bought new battery for my laptop. It is running Ubuntu MATE 16.04.5 LTS.

This new battery have normal capacity, charging and provides long life :)

But I have small problem: when battery level goes under some level - the laptop shutdowns immediately. I remember, that it normally went to the suspend with old battery.

With new battery I can suspend manually and all suspend-related tests (such as `pm-is-supported --suspend`, `pm-is-supported --hibernate`, `pm-is-supported --suspend-hybrid`) returns 0, so these actions are supported.

For more predictive results I have reseted all settings with

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.mate.power-manager
```

So my GSettings reports the following:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | egrep "critical|action|low|time" | grep -i power | sort -u
org.mate.power-manager action-critical-battery 'hibernate'
org.mate.power-manager action-critical-ups 'shutdown'
org.mate.power-manager action-low-ups 'hibernate'
org.mate.power-manager action-sleep-type-ac 'suspend'
org.mate.power-manager action-sleep-type-battery 'hibernate'
org.mate.power-manager idle-dim-time 10
org.mate.power-manager info-history-time 21600
org.mate.power-manager notify-low-capacity true
org.mate.power-manager notify-low-power true
org.mate.power-manager percentage-action 2
org.mate.power-manager percentage-critical 3
org.mate.power-manager percentage-low 10
org.mate.power-manager show-actions true
org.mate.power-manager time-action 120
org.mate.power-manager time-critical 300
org.mate.power-manager time-low 1200
org.mate.power-manager use-time-for-policy true
```

In `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` I have default values:

```
$ cat /etc/UPower/UPower.conf | grep -v ^# | egrep "Critical|Low|Action|Time"
PercentageLow=10
PercentageCritical=3
PercentageAction=2
TimeLow=1200
TimeCritical=300
TimeAction=120
CriticalPowerAction=HybridSleep
```

The MATE Power Management Preferences (`mate-power-preferences`) does not have GUI element to set critical battery level:

[image: mate-power-preferences]

Where should I set critical battery level for hibernate or suspend from MATE GUI?
Will changing value via GSettings or Dconf change value in `UPower.conf`?
Where else should I set the action on critical battery level?

---

Updates:
1. Laptop model is Asustek UX32A.
Output of `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/uevent`:

```
POWER_SUPPLY_NAME=BAT0
POWER_SUPPLY_STATUS=Discharging
POWER_SUPPLY_PRESENT=1
POWER_SUPPLY_TECHNOLOGY=Li-ion
POWER_SUPPLY_CYCLE_COUNT=481
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_MIN_DESIGN=7400000
POWER_SUPPLY_VOLTAGE_NOW=7400000
POWER_SUPPLY_POWER_NOW=11151000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL_DESIGN=48248000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_FULL=50038000
POWER_SUPPLY_ENERGY_NOW=46346000
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY=92
POWER_SUPPLY_CAPACITY_LEVEL=Normal
POWER_SUPPLY_MODEL_NAME=UX32-65
POWER_SUPPLY_MANUFACTURER=ASUSTeK
POWER_SUPPLY_SERIAL_NUMBER=
```

and output of `upower --dump`:

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun Nov  4 12:43:52 2018 (233 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                UX32-65
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun Nov  4 12:45:52 2018 (113 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              46.509 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         46.916 Wh
    energy-full-design:  48.248 Wh
    energy-rate:         11.514 W
    voltage:             7.4 V
    time to empty:       4.0 hours
    percentage:          92%
    capacity:            81.4562%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (charge):
    1541324752  92.000  discharging
  History (rate):
    1541324752  11.514  discharging

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Sun Nov  4 12:45:52 2018 (113 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              46.509 Wh
    energy-full:         46.916 Wh
    energy-rate:         11.514 W
    time to empty:       4.0 hours
    percentage:          92%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Daemon:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      yes
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep
```

2. TLP is not installed on my system.
3. I have reseted all settings with no luck. Todat I asked [question on Ubuntu-MATE.community](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/hibernate-suspend-on-critical-battery-level-where-should-i-set-it-from-mate-gui/18262?u=norbert_x).

Comment: What make and model of laptop? Does `/sys/class/power_supply/BAT1/*` report correct readings for battery?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix updated. My main question - where can I adjust critical level? Am I missed some other settings location?

Comment: Critical Battery is normally about 3%. There should be warnings popping up around 5 to 10% I think. Are you using `tlp` or any other third-party power management tools?

Comment: Tlp is not installed on my system. Currently MATE shows warning about critical battery level then starting shutdown procedure instead of Suspend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't find GUI solution for my problem. So I switched to semi-GUI solution.

I fixed this issue by using other battery level indicator - it is named `fdpowermon`:

> Description-en: simple battery power monitor for laptops with ACPI
>
> `fdpowermon` is a simple perl script that installs an icon in a system tray compatible with the freedesktop.org specification.
>   Every three seconds, `fdpowermon` calls `acpi` to find out what the current 
>   battery level is. It will set the output of the `acpi` command as a 
>   tooltip text, and will update the used icon as appropriate.
>   In addition, `fdpowermon` can optionally call perl subroutines when the 
>   power reaches a given level. No such subroutines are provided or 
>   enabled by default, however.

So I have installed it

```
sudo apt-get install fdpowermon
```

and created configuration folder for this application with:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/fdpowermon/
```

and placed here two files:

1. file with my modified theme (in `discharging` array note the 3rd element `20:battery-low.png`, it will be used to suspend in Perl script):

```
cat << \EOF > ~/.config/fdpowermon/theme.cfg 
[mytheme]
steps = 8
dir = /usr/share/icons/oxygen/22x22/status
# The below line makes fdpowermon not show an icon when the power is
# connected and the battery is completely full. This is by design,
# because that's how the author likes to use the software, and he is of
# the opinion that it's easier to ship software configured just the way
# he likes it rather than to have to reconfigure things.
#
# Requests are often made to change this default. This will not happen,
# but it's an easy change: just change the last entry in this "charging"
# configuration so that it says "100:battery-charging.png" rather than
# "99:battery-charging.png", and you're done!
charging = 0:battery-charging-low.png, 10:battery-charging-low.png, 20:battery-charging-caution.png, 30:battery-charging-caution.png, 50:battery-charging-040.png, 70:battery-charging-060.png, 90:battery-charging-080.png,100:battery-charging.png
discharging = 2:battery-missing.png:battery-low.png,10:battery-low.png, 20:battery-low.png,30:battery-caution.png,50:battery-040.png,70:battery-060.png,90:battery-080.png,100:battery-100.png
EOF
```

2. Perl script file with dbus suspend action:

```
cat << \EOF > ~/.config/fdpowermon/theme.pl
# Copy this file to ~/.config/fdpowermon/theme.pl.
#
# If you don't like the 'default' theme, define a new one by copying
# /etc/fdpowermon/theme.cfg to ~/.config/fdpowermon/theme.cfg and
# renaming/adjusting the 'default' theme there to something new.
# Don't forget to replace "default" below with your new theme name.
#
# See the manpage fdpowermon(1) for full details on what you can do
# here.

# define a suspend action
sub suspend {
    system("dbus-send --print-reply --system --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend boolean:true");
}

# initialize our theme, from /etc/fdpowermon/theme.cfg or
# ~/.config/fdpowermon/theme.cfg
my $theme = fdpowermon::theme::get_theme("mytheme");

# on the discharge event for the lowest element in the list of steps (0 = first
# in the index, "d" for discharge), call the "suspend" sub defined above
$theme->set_event( 2, \&suspend, 'd' );
EOF
```

(the DBus suspend command came from [this great answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/699721/66509)).

And finally I have disabled MATE Power Manager battery indicator with

```
gsettings set org.mate.power-manager icon-policy 'never'
```

and created auto-start desktop file to have `fdpowermon` shown in the tray instead:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart

cat << EOF > ~/.config/autostart/fdpowermon.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=fdpowermon
Hidden=false
X-MATE-Autostart-enabled=true
Name[en_US]=fdpowermon
Name=fdpowermon
Comment[en_US]=
Comment=
EOF
```

As the result I have nice-looking battery icon in the tray from [image: battery-charging] to [image: battery-caution] and [image: battery-low] and system automatically suspends on 20% battery level (the level is configurable, but my new battery seems to report low values wrongly).

Answer (score 2):

## GUI method

From: [Change Critical Battery Level and Action in Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon](http://www.putdispenserhere.com/change-critical-battery-level-action-linux-mint-18-cinnamon/)
you can install `dconf-editor` using:

```
$ sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Then go to **org -> cinnamon -> settings-daemon -> plugins -> power**

[image: mate gsettings power.png]

- Default settings are (in %):
- Critical battery action: hibernate
- Critical: 2
- Action: 2
- Low: 10

Exercise caution and tweak to your heart’s content

---

### Original Answer and edits below

#### Review your current settings with:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep critical
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'shutdown'
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power percentage-critical 3
org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power time-critical 300
```

#### Change your `critical-battery-action`

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power critical-battery-action 'suspend'
```

---

### Linux Mate differences

When using Linux Mate you need to substitute `org.gnome` with `org.mate` and possibly change your keys. From [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MATE):

#### Battery discharge

To disable the notification on battery discharge, run:

```
$ gsettings set org.mate.power-manager.notify-discharging false
```

However in Ubuntu there is no equivalent.

### Find all Mate power settings

To find all Mate power settings use:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep power-manager
```

In Ubuntu you would use:

```
$ gsettings list-recursively | grep plugins.power
```

Comment: I'm using MATE, dear @WinEunuuchs2Unix. So `/usr/bin/gnome-settings-daemon` is not running on my system.

Comment: Yikes I though all roads led to gnome :( From: https://mate-desktop.org/ it says: *"The MATE Desktop Environment is the continuation of GNOME 2. It provides an intuitive and attractive desktop environment using traditional metaphors for Linux and other Unix-like operating systems."*

Comment: I've updated answer by reading Archwiki which gave me enough hints without installing Mate (a last resort). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: OK I found the GUI method which **SHOULD** work for you now :)

Comment: Cinnamon and MATE are different DEs ... I'll charge the battery and test again.

Comment: Replace author's `cinnamon` reference with `mate` inside `dconf-editor`. Using the GUI editor you should be able to easily navigate among all possible settings a lot quicker than using `gsettings`.