# New battery - wrong / missing status shown in ubuntu

Tags: kernel, power-management, battery, charging

I just replaced the battery for my notebook, the old one was 5.2Ah, the new one is 4.4Ah. Ubuntu does not show any usefull information (all values at 0 and power level at 100%).

Is there any module i need to unload/load or can i run some config tool to fix this?

My Ubuntu Version is 16.04.6
Kernel is 4.15.0-46-generic
The notebook type is ASUS A53SK

Kind regards

**update**

Here is my upower dump

```
Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
native-path:          AC0
power supply:         yes
updated:              Son 17 Mär 2019 15:25:01 CET (145 seconds ago)
has history:          no
has statistics:       no
line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
native-path:          BAT0
power supply:         yes
updated:              Son 17 Mär 2019 15:27:02 CET (24 seconds ago)
has history:          yes
has statistics:       yes
battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-full-design:  0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          100%
    capacity:            100%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Device: /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/DisplayDevice
power supply:         yes
updated:              Son 17 Mär 2019 15:25:01 CET (145 seconds ago)
has history:          no
has statistics:       no
battery
    present:             yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              0 Wh
    energy-full:         0 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    percentage:          100%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'

Daemon:
daemon-version:  0.99.4
on-battery:      yes
lid-is-closed:   no
lid-is-present:  yes
critical-action: HybridSleep
```

Comment: It is very likely battery controller issue. I have had somehow [similar problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/1088237/66509) with noname battery. The levels of new batter were changed on hardware level. Please add output of `upower --dump` to the question.

Comment: First question... why would you install a lower Ah battery? Second, the power controller may need to be reset. Disconnect ALL power from the notebook, including the battery, and hold down the power key for 15 seconds. Reconnect the battery, and AC power, and see if there's any change. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: @N0rbert: I added the dump to the original post

Comment: @heynnema i did not have the choice for a bigger battery but the old one was done so i bought what was available. Tried your solution - turned off the computer, removed the battery, pressed power button for ~ 15-20 seconds, re-install battery, plugin in the computer, turn it on again... no difference

Comment: See https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FMPEX5G?tag=amz-mkt-fox-us-20&ascsubtag=1ba00-01000-a0047-linux-dsk00-nomod-us000-pcomp-feature-scomp-wm-5&ref=aa_scomp , and Google search for "ASUS A53SK battery" turns up a lot of choices :-)