# Suspend, hangs after GPU is used

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, suspend

### **Problem**

On normal occasions when `xorg` and `compiz` is running in my gpu, I
can `Suspend` peacefully. However if I run some **intense** (90% GPU
in use) training (via jupyter) related to `pytorch`, and subsequently
suspend after the processes are over, it refuses to sleep/wakeup.

I am positive GPU being full or not empty is causing the issue. I
don't know why "some process" possibly related to the GPU is not
Suspending. When I run `jupyter` and run `1+1` (or a simple process)
and `Suspend`, then also no issues.

### **Question**

Kernlog shows me nothing "fishy". I have tried a bunch of online
remedies. Now at a dead end.

How do I identify what is happening? any ideas?

**Other symptoms**

It sort-of sleeps but I still hear some sound from the laptop when I
hit a key (it sounds as if it is booting up). And then blank screen
after that. Sometimes I get to go to the TTY but can't type anything.

---

**My system**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Nvidia 1050 GeForce
- Acer nitro 5 8gb ram

### **What all I tried to rectify this issue?**

Spent a good 5 full days understanding and searching and re-installing
etc... Now at a dead end.

0. Checked the [kern logs (pastebin link)](https://pastebin.com/B1TNtKPt) but didn't see anything
   "fishy". (at `02:08` I start sleeping and at `10:21` I hit hard
   reset).

   Here is a tiny exerpt:

```
Oct  2 02:08:06 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597286.6443] manager: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Oct  2 02:08:06 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597286.6443] manager: sleeping...
Oct  2 02:08:06 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597286.6447] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Oct  2 02:08:06 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597286.6453] device (wlp2s0): state change: activated -> deactivating (reason 'sleeping') [100 110 37]
Oct  2 02:08:06 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597286.8169] device (wlp2s0): state change: deactivating -> disconnected (reason 'sleeping') [110 30 37]
Oct  2 02:08:06 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597286.8356] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 8328
Oct  2 02:08:06 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597286.8356] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed bound -> done
Oct  2 02:08:06 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597286.8363] dns-mgr: Writing DNS information to /sbin/resolvconf
Oct  2 02:08:06 eghx-nitro kernel: [24100.153393] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from e8:cc:18:41:3c:15 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Oct  2 02:08:07 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <warn>  [1601597287.0509] sup-iface[0xb4a6f0,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Oct  2 02:08:07 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597287.0511] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Oct  2 02:08:07 eghx-nitro NetworkManager[8152]: <info>  [1601597287.0525] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping') [30 10 37]
Oct  2 02:08:08 eghx-nitro kernel: [24101.983885] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Oct  2 02:08:09 eghx-nitro kernel: [24101.983888] PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
Oct  2 10:21:32 eghx-nitro kernel: [24103.953554] Freezing user space
processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
```

1. Based on [Nvidia forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/solved-suspend-resuming-and-wakeup-with-nvidia370-28/45282) added the following to grub and updated.

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi_rev_override=1
    acpi_osi=Linux scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 nouveau.modeset=0
    nouveau.runpm=0 mem_sleep_default=deep"
   ```

   Added the following to iniramfs-tools/modules and updated.

   ```
    nvidia
    nvidia_modeset
    nvidia_uvm
    nvidia_drm
   ```
2. Didn't change kernel as there was no evidence towards it. People
   changed to 4.17. Mine is currently 4.15.

   - [4.17 but it didn't work](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-with-resume-from-suspend-ubuntu-16-04-gt-940mx/51410/63)
   - [Another user](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-with-resume-from-suspend-ubuntu-16-04-gt-940mx/51410/77)
   - [this guy](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-with-resume-from-suspend-ubuntu-16-04-gt-940mx/51410/69)
3. Blind try: Trying different ([Suspend](https://askubuntu.com/a/1795/443958))s

   ```
    systemctl suspend

    pm-suspend
   ```
4. Tried downgrading the drivers to 384 from 430 with changing it at
   `additional drivers`. This was not useful as this was not capable
   of co-existing with `pytorch=1.6.0`
5. Complete remove and re-install of `nvdia-430` as per [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/760935/443958):
   `purge`, `add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`, `update`
   and `autoinstall`.

   This ended in the black screen of death. Recovered it with
   `noveau.modeset=0`. Somehow GPU was not working anymore.
6. At this point did a [complete re-install](https://askubuntu.com/a/760935/443958) of `xserver`,`unity`,
   `lightdm` and `nvidia-430` over tty terminal before login screen.

   This recovered the system to it's previous state i.e., `suspend`
   when GPU full hangs the system.