# How to hiberate from the command-line in Cinnamon Desktop

Tags: command-line, xubuntu, hibernate, cinnamon

I just installed Xubuntu 22.04.1 a few days ago, and then installed Cinnamon desktop on it. I'm very happy with it, but I'm not sure how to make it hibernate. There was a GUI option on XFCE (if enabled), but on Cinnamon, I only see options for suspending/sleep.

Anyway, I was wondering if there was a command-line way of making it hibernate--and particularly if there's a Cinnamon-specific way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I suspend/hibernate from command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line)

Comment: It answers a good part of it, but doesn't address whether or not there's a Cinnamon-specific way).

Comment: For instance, there is a Cinnamon-specific way for making it sleep (not sure about hibernating). I'll edit the question to distinguish it more, since I didn't technically ask that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is possibly that there isn't one that's Cinnamon-specific (someone else please answer if I'm wrong). For general-purposes (not Cinnamon), see the [possible duplicate question/answers mentioned by guiverc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line).

The keyboard shortcut for hibernating (if you set it up) in Cinnamon doesn't work either. However, you can set up Cinnamon-specific keyboard shortcuts for shutting down and suspending (without having to enter a root password), but these methods don't reveal command-line ways of doing them. You can also set the power switch to do those things. You can, however, lock the screen from the command-line in a Cinnamon-specific way: `cinnamon-screensaver-command -l`.