Putting machine to sleep via keyboard - what's the equivalent command?
I sometimes put my (Ubuntu 22.04) machine to sleep by pressing the "power" button on my keyboard.
Do we know what is the equivalent command line command? I'd like to compare it to the command line I usually use to send the machine to sleep.

Ubuntu 22?   Are you using Ubuntu Core 22? as that's usually used headless on devices/cloud.

@guiverc the user history suggests v22.04

The question was not how to hibernate or sleep from command line. The questin was: do we know what exact command does the "power" button execute.

People often labour under a misconception that GUIs run commands underneath. The reality is the opposite, they usually don't run commands. Instead, they use APIs (just like those commands do) directly. The power button on your system sends a signal, probably using ACPI, and your desktop then handles it, highly likely without running any commands at all.

Right, but there must be command line equivalent, or closest match. Btw, your comment seems like a good answer.

The command will vary on what you're using; I'm using LXQt currently thus I could use the lxqt-leave --suspend which will ask my GUI to perform a suspend.. If you're using a different desktop/GUI that command of course will differ  (ie. the desktop I'm using no with my Lubuntu session makes request via API on my behalf to suspend machine; though I still get asked to confirm identically to if I'd selected Leave-Suspend at the menu)

Aside from lxqt-suspend and similar, the answers using DBus in  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1792/how-can-i-suspend-hibernate-from-command-line are often the closest equivalents, since they use DBus to ask the GUI to do whatever it normally does for suspend/hibernate.
